# Python: inheritance of class data (if superclass object has been already initialized)

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I faced with an inability of the inheritance of superclass attribute values. I have already called superclass constructor and now trying to check out the inherited values.

```
class base:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        print(self.x)

class derive(base):
    def __init__(self):
        print(self.x + 1)


print("base class: ")
b = base(1)                           <-- Creating superclass instance 
print("derive class: ")
d = derived()                         <-- Inheriting. Failure.
```

Why can't I do this? Should I pass the underlying object to the inheriting object explicitly in order to get *x* attribute?

Comment: You need to call the base class `__init__` from the derived class.  There are many previous questions on this issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use 'super' in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222877/how-to-use-super-in-python)

Comment: @shx2: That question is rather Python 2-specific in its answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`b` and `d` are not related; `b` is entirely a *separate* instance of the base class.

If you want to invoke the overridden initializer (`__init__`), then use the [`super()` proxy object](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) to access it:

```
class derive(base):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(1)
        print(self.x + 1)
```

Note that you still need to pass in an argument to the initializer of the parent class. In the above example, I pass in a constant value 1 for the `x` parameter of the parent initializer.

Note that I used Python 3 specific syntax here; `super()` without arguments won't work in Python 2, where you also need to use `object` as a parent for the `base` class to make it a new-style class.

Comment: @zero323: The OP is using `print()` functions; I stuck to Python 3 for that reason.

Comment: Sometimes I feel like the only one using `print()` and Python 2.x

Comment: @zero323: Don't, unless you use `from __future__ import print_function`.