# Behavior difference between super().__init__() and explicit superclass __init__() in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, super, keyword-argument

I am getting an unexplained difference in behavior between using `super().__init__()` and explicitly calling a super class constructor in my code.

```
class IPElement(object):

def __init__(self, ip_type='IPv4'):
    self.ip_type = ip_type

class IPAddressSimple(IPElement):

    def __init__(self, ip_name, ip_type='IPv4'):
        self.ip_name = ip_name
        super().__init__(self, ip_type=ip_type)
```

Here, the line `super().__init__(self, ip_type=ip_type)` results in a type error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'ip_type'
```

When I change the call to pass `ip_type` by position (e.g. `super().__init__(self, ip_type)` I get a different type error:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Neither of these errors makes sense to me, and when I replace `super()` with the explicit name of the superclass, everything works as expected.  The following works just fine, as does passing ip_type by position:

```
class IPAddressSimple(IPElement):

        def __init__(self, ip_name, ip_type='IPv4'):
            self.ip_name = ip_name
            IPElement.__init__(self, ip_type=ip_type)
```

I can certainly use an explicit call to the superclass `__init__` method if necessary, but I would like to understand why `super()` is not working here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does 'super' do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222877/what-does-super-do-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`super()` already passes `self` along for you. `super(IPAddressSimple)` would not know about `self`, so in that case you'd need to call `super(IPAddressSimple).__init__(self, ip_type)`. But `super()` (which is syntactic sugar for `super(IPAddressSimple, self)`) knows `self` and handles it, so you should only pass `ip_type` manually.

Comment: As always, the most baffling issues turn out to have the simplest explanations.  Thanks for the clear, concise answer!