# What is the practical use of the keyword super in Python inheritance?

Tags: python, django

I sort of understand that the keyword `super` in the `ChildClass` that inherits from a `BaseClass` is to prevent the overriding of the the base's class method when a `ChildClass` has the same method. What is the practical use of this?

For example:

```
class BaseClass():
    def save(*args, **kwargs):
        print "save from BaseClass"

class ChildClass(BaseClass):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ChildClass, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        print "save from ChildClass"


someObject = ChildClass()
someObject.save()
​
```

Output:

```
save from BaseClass
save from ChildClass
```

Comment: `super()` doesn't call anything; you still have to call the parent method explicitly. It gives you access to the implementation of a method on a parent class, so you can *re-use* that implementation as needed.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what your question is here though. What if `ChildClass.save()` had to do some additional processing, but you don't want to replicate *all the work* `BaseClass.save()` does? That's where `super()` comes in, you can reuse the original `save()` method without having to do all that work again, but you can add to the original behaviour whilst presenting a consistent API to the users of `ChildClass`.

Comment: I *think* what you are asking about is what the use is of calling the parent method, but you could be asking about something else entirely.

Comment: Have you read e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/222877/3001761? http://stackoverflow.com/q/576169/3001761?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: thank you for illustrating my point; it could be that the OP is asking about using `super()` vs. naming the base class method directly.

Comment: I've edited the question. I'm looking for practical use why would you do both somemethod() from BaseClass and somemethod() from ChildClass?

Comment: Imagine that `BaseClass.save()` can store some document, but does not inform an user about save status. So, you can `extend BaseClass` and call `super.save(...)` (to save the document) and than inform the user about the save status... Why do you call with `super` prefix? As your child method calls exactly as parent (`.save(...)`), you need to tell to compiler to call parent save. If you don't do that, it will call itself infinitely and throw an error...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I sort of understand that...

You have had two attempts at this, neither correct:

- *"will call both the parent's class method and the child's class method"* - no, it calls the method on the next class in the MRO (Method Resolution Order); and
- *"is to prevent the overriding of the the base's class method when a `ChildClass` has the same method"* - no, the child class implementation **does** override the base class, `super` allows you to access inherited implementations without explicitly specifying  a class.

---

> What is the practical use of this?

At the very simplest, imagine that we have a base class with one initialisation parameter:

```
def Base(object):

    def __init__(self, attr1):
        self.attr1 = attr1
```

and a child class with two. Then we can implement the child in one of two ways, either without calling the base class:

```
def Child(Base):

    def __init__(self, attr1, attr2):
        self.attr1 = attr1 
        self.attr2 = attr2
```

or by calling the base class:

```
def Child(Base):

    def __init__(self, attr1, attr2):
        super(Child, self).__init__(attr1)
        self.attr2 = attr2
```

Note that this reduces repetition, and if we change the handling of `attr1` in the `Base` class (e.g. we assign the parameter to a "private" attribute `_attr1` and access it via a `@property`) we **only have to make that change once**.

---

You could also implement the second as:

```
def __init__(self, attr1, attr2):
    Base.__init__(self, attr1)
    self.attr2 = attr2
```

but this again means repetition - we've now had to specify the name `Base` in two places in `Child`, so if we rename the `Base` or change the inheritance for `Child` we have to make alterations in two places.

Comment: Ok thanks for correcting me and for your explanations. In that case I don't completely understand it at all. That's why my question starts with I "sort of"