# PySide: 'PySide.QtCore.Signal' object has no attribute 'emit'

Tags: python, qt, pyside

With the following code, I get an error (`'PySide.QtCore.Signal' object has no attribute 'emit'`) when trying to emit a signal:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from PySide import QtCore

class TestSignalClass(QtCore.QObject):
    somesignal = QtCore.Signal()

    def speak_me(self):
        self.speak.emit()
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            self.somesignal.emit()
        except Exception as e:
            print("__init__:")
            print(e)

t = TestSignalClass()
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem here is that although the class correctly inherits from `QtCore.QObject`, it does not call the parent's constructor.  This version works fine:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from PySide import QtCore

class TestSignalClass(QtCore.QObject):
    somesignal = QtCore.Signal()

    def speak_me(self):
        self.speak.emit()
    def __init__(self):
        # Don't forget super(...)!
        super(TestSignalClass, self).__init__()
        try:
            self.somesignal.emit()
        except Exception as e:
            print("__init__:")
            print(e)

t = TestSignalClass()
```

Comment: After searching on a lot of stack overflow answers, this is what solved it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The solution above is "odd" to me... thus I'm providing mine below...

```
from PySide2.QtCore import Signal, QObject

class myTestObject(QObject):
    someSignal = Signal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)  # call to initialize properly
        self.someSignal.connect(self.testSignal)  # test connect
        self.someSignal.emit("Wowz")  # test

    def testSignal(self, arg):
        print("my signal test from init fire", arg)
```

Comment: Why do you use the parent's name (`QObject`) explicitly instead of using `super` and what exactly is odd about the other answer? You may want to read https://stackoverflow.com/q/222877.