# How to initialize subclass parameters in python using super()

Tags: python, inheritance, super

I have seen various examples on [How to use 'super' in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222877/how-to-use-super-in-python), but in all of these examples, there are no arguments being passed to the subclass' init method. Consider the following example.

Here is the base class:

```
class Animal(object):

    def __init__(self, genus):
        self.genus = genus
```

Now heres without using super:

```
class Dog(Animal):

    def __init__(self, genus):
        Animal.__init__(self, genus)


x = Dog('Canis')
print x.genus  # Successfully prints "Canis"
```

Now when I use super instead:

```
class Dog(Animal):

    def __init__(self, genus):
        super(Animal, self).__init__(genus)

x = Dog('Canis')
print x.genus
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters
```

So then if object.**init**() takes no parameters, how to I set the specific genus of this particular animal when instantiated that subclass? Do I have to explicitly assign the variables like this:

```
class Dog(Animal):

    def __init__(self, genus):
        super(Animal, self).__init__()
        self.genus = genus
```

Comment: The point of `super` is that you always use the *current* class.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### The fix

Write:

```
class Dog(Animal):

    def __init__(self, genus):
        super(Dog, self).__init__(genus)
```

So instead of:

```
super(Animal, self).__init__(genus)
```

use:

```
super(Dog, self).__init__(genus)
```

Think of: What is the super class of `Dog`? `Animal` would be the right answer to this questions for this case. But if you use multiple inheritance this can be different.

### Python 3 for the rescue

If you use Python 3, all things get simpler:

```
class Dog(Animal):

    def __init__(self, genus):
        super().__init__(genus)
```

works. Much less surface for making a mistake.

### Python 3 niceties in Python 2 with Python-Future

If you need to work with Python 2, consider [Python-Future](http://python-future.org/). Than you can do this on Python 2:

```
from builtins import object, super

class Animal(object):

    def __init__(self, genus):
        self.genus = genus

class Dog(Animal):

    def __init__(self, genus):
        super().__init__(genus)

x = Dog('Canis')
print(x.genus)
```

This `builtins` module comes from Python-Future. Using it, allows you to program Python 3 in Python 2 (at least for all important changes).