# How does python variable inheritance work?

Tags: python, inheritance

I'm trying something very basic with Python inheritance:

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.text = 'parent'

    def getText(self):
        print self.text

class Child1(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 'x'

class Child2(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 'x'

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    parent = Parent()
    child1 = Child1()
    child2 = Child2()

    parent.getText()
    child1.getText()
    child2.getText()
```

but I keep getting

> Child1 instance has no attribute 'text'

how are variables passed to children?

Comment: You need to call the constructor of the parent classes manually - Here, `self.text` is initialize in `Parent` constructor which is never called.

Comment: @Holt what would that be? `super().__init__()` ?

Comment: @deceze no they're not. I put `self.x = 'x'` to stop the compiler from complaining about indenting block expected

Comment: @Abdul I misread. For that purpose you should just use `pass`, that's what it's for (a dummy body).

Comment: If you don't want python complaining about empty block, use `pass`, e.g. `if a: pass` (only for demonstration purpose).

Comment: In addition to `pass`, if the block is also a function, then adding a docstring also works to prevent python from complaining about the indentation being wrong.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to call the constructor of the parent classes manually - Here, `self.text` is initialize in `Parent` constructor which is never called:

```
class Child1(Parent):
    def __init__ (self):
        super(Child1, self).__init__ ()
        # or Parent.__init__ (self)
        self.x = 'x'
```

Comment: any reason why I would use `super` vs `Parent` init?

Comment: @AbdulAhmad There are multiple posts on SO about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222877/how-to-use-super-in-python, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-with-init-methods. I personally use `super` most of the time.

Comment: one more question, what's the correct way of altering the `self.text` from parent in a child? just `self.text = 'new text'`? or is there another way more suited for inheritance? (I will accept the answer once the timer is down, have 2 minutes left)

Comment: @AbdulAhmad You're just setting an attribute on the `self` object, it's no different than altering it in another method of the object. Just assign a new value to it.

Answer (score 2):

Since python 3.6, we can now use the `__init_subclass__` function, which is called automatically before `__init__` of the Child.

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.text = 'parent'
    
    def __init_subclass__(self):
        Parent.__init__(self)

    def getText(self):
        print(self.text)

class Child1(Parent): pass
class Child2(Parent): pass

classes = [Parent(), Child1(), Child2()]

for item in classes:
    item.getText()
```

output

```
parent
parent
parent
```

If you use your Parent class more as a "interface", here is another example.

```
class Animal():
    def __init_subclass__(self, sound):
        self.sound = sound

    def make_sound(self):
        print(self.sound)

class Cat(Animal, sound='meow'): pass
class Dog(Animal, sound='woof'): pass

animals = [Cat(), Dog()]

for animal in animals:
    animal.make_sound()
```

output

```
meow
woof
```

Answer (score 1):

your init function needs to call the parent init

```
class Child1(Parent):
def __init__(self):
    self.x = 'x'
    Parent.__init__(self)
```

Answer (score 1):

In python when you override a function which was supposed to be inherited you override all of it, __init__ is no exception. You should call the functions [super](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super) method to use the base initializer, or implement the attribute in the constructor you have rewrote.

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.text = 'parent'

    def getText(self):
        print self.text

class Child1(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Child1, self).__init__()
        self.x = 'x'

child1.getText()
```

Should work now.