# what does multiple __init__ in a single class do?

Tags: python, class

New python learner here, when i was watching some tutorials i stumbled upon a code like this:

```
from character import *


class enemy(Character):
    def __init__(self, name, hp, str)
        Character.__init__(self, name, hp)
```

What exactly does the following code do in this case? First time seeing multiple **_init** _in a single class and i can't seem to understand this type of code.

```
Character.__init__(self, name, hp)
```

the character file code is here:

```
class Character(object):

def __init__(self, name, hp):
    self.name = name
    self.hp = hp
def attack(self,other):
    pass
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `enemy` defines its own `__init__` method, it overwrites the one on the `Character` class.  Therefore, when you use `enemy()`, the `__init__` method that was defined for the `Character` class is not called.  To make sure that it is called anyway, the `__init__` method in `enemy` calls it itself.  The `__init__` method that was defined in `Character` is still an instance method, but it is hidden by the new `__init__` method that took its place.  If you say `self.__init__()`, it is a shortcut for `enemy.__init__(self)`.  In this case, we don't want to call the `enemy` `__init__` method; we want to call the `Character` `__init__` method, so we don't use `self.__init__()`.  Instead of using the shortcut that is often used, we instead call the `Character` `__init__` method directly with `Character.__init__(self)`.  As @kevin mentioned in a comment on another post, it is common to use the `super()` function here:

```
super().__init__() # In Python3, or
super(enemy, self).__init__() # In Python2
```

Answer (score 3):

It's calling the constructor of the `enemy` classes' superclass, `Character`. When a class (like `enemy`) inherits from a class (in this case `Character`) it needs to ensure that the superclass is set up correctly, and thus needs to call `__init__` on the superclass.

**Update**: there's actually two ways to call the constructor of a superclass - as you've posted above and with the `super` function. Rather than reposting something that's been discussed many times, I'll direct you to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222877/how-to-use-super-in-python).