# appended list item appearing 2 times

Tags: python, odoo

The action module takes as origin 'audit' audit module, when I try this code:
in audit.py:

```
 class action(orm.Model):
 _inherit = "action"
 def __init__(self, pool, cr):
    """Add a new audit value"""
    return super(action, self).Origin_SELECTION.append(('audit', 'Audit'))
```

in action.py we have:

```
Origin_SELECTION=[('dysfunction','Dysfunction')]
origin_act = fields.Selection(Origin_SELECTION, 'Origin')
```

in the final selection field the 'audit' choice appeared 2 times.

Comment: I don't think you're using `super` correctly. See ["How to use `super` in Python"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222877/how-to-use-super-in-python).

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

class my_model(orm.Model):
    _inherit = 'my.model'

```
def _type_selection(self, cr, uid, context=None):
    selection = super(my_model, self)._type_selection(cr, uid, context=context)
    selection.append(('special', 'Special'))
    return selection
```

Comment: it's not working, the new selection field dosn't appear at all.

Comment: You need to restart your server.

Comment: I did, still have the same problem