# AttributeError: object has no attribute 'tk'

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, registration, mysql-connector

I have searched quite a bit,but I couldn't find a solution to this. I'm trying to create a registration form using tkinter which later on i shall connect to a database. Here is the code :

```
from Tkinter import *


class MWindow(object):

    def __init__(self,master):

        self.frame=Frame(master)
        self.frame.pack()

        self.title= Label(self,text = "Login")
        self.title.grid(row=0,column=1)

        self.userid_label = Label(self,text ="Username: ")
        self.userid_label.grid(row=1,column=0)

        self.userid_entry= Entry(self)
        self.userid_entry.grid(row=1,column=1)

        self.password_label = Label(self,text ="Password: ")
        self.password_label.grid(row=2,column=0)

        self.password_entry= Entry(self)
        self.password_entry.grid(row=2,column=1)

        self.signin = Button (self,text = "Login",command=logging_in)
        self.signin.grid(row=5,column=1)

        self.signup = Button (self,text = "Sign Up",command=signing_up)
        self.signin.grid(row=5,column=2)

    def logging_in(self):
        pass
    def signing_up(self):
        pass

root= Tk()
root.attributes('-fullscreen',True)
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root.title("My Registration Form")
app=MWindow(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Here is the error i get :

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "form.py", line 41, in 
>       app=MWindow(root)
>     File "form.py", line 11, in **init**
>       self.title= Label(self,text = "Login")
>     File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 2591, in **init**
>       Widget.**init**(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
>     File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 2081, in **init**
>       BaseWidget._setup(self, master, cnf)
>     File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 2059, in _setup
>       self.tk = master.tk
>   AttributeError: 'MWindow' object has no attribute 'tk'

I tried going to the library files to understand what's wrong,but being a beginner i can't make much of it. Some explanation of what's going wrong and why would be very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing `self` in as the master / parent to your widgets.

e.g - `Entry(self, ...)` But, your class `MWindow` doesn't inherit from a Tkinter widget.

Perhaps you meant to use `self.frame`?

If you really want to use **`self`** you could do this:

```
import Tkinter as tk

...

class MWindow(tk.Frame):

   def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):

       tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
       abutton = tk.Button(self, ....)
```

If this is confusing, then here's a pretty good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222877/how-to-use-super-in-python/33469090#33469090).

Since you mentioned the [source code](http://mgltools.scripps.edu/api/DejaVu/Tkinter-pysrc.html)....

Look at the `Tk()` class. Which contains the following line:

```
self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
```

Now, check out the `BaseWidget` class which all `Widget`'s inherit from. This contains the following line:

```
self.tk = master.tk
```

You have you're base root window `Tk()` which has the attribute `tk` and every child of this set's an attribute `tk` to be the `master`'s tk attribute. So on and so forth for nested widgets, since the parent of a widget could just be another widget it doesn't have to be the root window of course.

Comment: thanks a lot! it runs without any error now and i think i've got quite a lot to wrap my head around. But i get a blank window now without the text or buttons,any idea?

Comment: If you changed to the `class ClsName(tk.Frame): ...` method, then you'll need to pack / grid this into the root window. e.g. - `root = tk.Tk() app = MWindow(root) app.pack()` or you could do `self.pack()/grid()` in the class

Comment: ah..missed the pack(). Thanks again.