# How can I add to the initial definition of a python class inheriting from another class?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, instance

I'm trying to define `self.data` inside a class inheriting from a class

```
class Object():
    def __init__(self):
        self.data="1234"

class New_Object(Object):
    # Code changing self.data here
```

But I ran into an issue.

```
class Object():
    def __init__(self):
        self.data="1234"
```

So I have the beginning class here, which is imported from elsewhere, and let's say that the class is a universal one so I can't modify the original at all.

In the original, the instance is referred to as "`self`" inside the class, and it is defined as self inside the definition `__init__`.

```
class New_Object(Object):
    # Code changing self.data here
```

So if I wanted to inherit from the class `Object`, but define self.data inside `New_Object`, I thought I would have to define `__init__` in `New_Object`, but this overrides the `__init__` from `New_Object`

Is there any way I could do this without copypasting the `__init__` from `Object`?

Comment: Any edits would be useful, I'm terrible at terminology and phrasing what I mean.

Comment: Note that `self` is an *instance* of the class, not the class itself.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Ah, thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `super` to call the original implementation.

```
class New_Object(Object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(NewObject, self).__init__()
        self.info = 'whatever'
```

Answer (score 2):

That's what [`super`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super) is for:

```
class NewObject(Object):

    def __init__(self):
        super(NewObject, self).__init__()
        # self.data exists now, and you can modify it if necessary
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `super().__init__()` to call `Object.__init__()` from `New_Object.__init__()`.

What you would do:

```
class Object:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Object init")
        self.data = "1234"

class New_Object(Object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("calling super")
        super().__init__()
        print("data is now", self.data)
        self.data = self.data.split("3")

o = New_Object()

# calling super
# Object init
# data is now 1234
```

Note that you do not have to give any arguments to `super()`, as long as you are using Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that you call the superclass's `__init__` explicitly during the subclass's `__init__`.   This can be done either of two ways:

```
Object.__init__(self)   # requires you to name the superclass explicitly
```

or

```
super(NewObject, self).__init__()   # requires you to name the subclass explicitly
```

The latter also requires you to ensure that you're using "new-style" classes: in Python 3 that's always the case, but in Python 2 you must be sure to inherit from the builtin `object` class.  In Python 3 it can actually be expressed even more simply:

```
super().__init__()
```

Personally, in most of my code the "disadvantage" of having to name the superclass explicitly is no disadvantage at all, and `Object.__init__()` lends transparency since it makes it absolutely clear what is being called. This is because most of my code is single-inheritance only. The `super` route comes into its own when you have multiple inheritance. See [What does 'super' do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222877/how-to-use-super-in-python)

Python 2 example:

```
class Object(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = "1234"

class NewObject:
    def __init__(self):
        # subclass-specific stuff
        super(NewObject, self).__init__()
        # more subclass-specific stuff
```