# About Inheritance and super()

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance, super

Given the code:

```
class Character():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.health = 50
        self.damage = 10

class Warrior(Character):
    def __init__(self, name, weapon, armor):
        super(Character).__init__()
        self.weapon = weapon
        self.armor = armor
        self.strength = 10
        self.dexterity = 5
        self.intelligence = 5

Doug = Character("Doug")
Mark = Warrior("Mark", "Axe", None)
```

---

Why doesn't the `Warrior` class inherit the `health` from the `Character` class? 
What would I need to do differently to be able to print `Mark.health`?

Comment: `super` is pretty tricky for several reasons; see http://stackoverflow.com/q/222877/1256452

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `super()` incorrectly; don't pass in `Character` on its own. In Python 3, don't pass anything in at all, but do pass `name` to `__init__`:

```
class Warrior(Character):
    def __init__(self, name, weapon, armor):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.weapon = weapon
        self.armor = armor
        self.strength = 10
        self.dexterity = 5
        self.intelligence = 5
```

Now attributes are set correctly, including `health` and `damage`:

```
>>> Mark = Warrior("Mark", "Axe", None)
>>> vars(Mark)
{'name': 'Mark', 'health': 50, 'damage': 10, 'weapon': 'Axe', 'armor': None, 'strength': 10, 'dexterity': 5, 'intelligence': 5}
```

Under the covers, `super(Character).__init__()` ends up calling the `super.__init__()` method which within a method on a class just happens to work but produces nothing of practical use (`None` is returned).

Comment: thank you, I've been having trouble grasping the concept of super, making small programs like this to practice. Your comment helped clear up some misunderstanding.

Comment: if the Character class took more parameters than just 'name' would I need to pass them to the __init__ as well?

Comment: @Matt: yes, because the `Character.__init__` method would require more parameters.