# What are some other ways to call the Parent's __init__ method besides super()?

Tags: python

I'm trying to have the Child class call and use the Parent's __init__method, what are some other ways to do this other than using the super() method in the Child? I was told to avoid using super() is possible hence I want to know.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

class Room(object):

    def __init__(self, current_room):
        self.current_room = current_room
        print("You are now in Room #{}".format(self.current_room))

class EmptyStartRoom(Room):

    def __init__(self, current_room=1):
        super().__init__(current_room)

class ChestRoomKey1(Room):

    def __init__(self, current_room=2):
        super().__init__(current_room)

a_room = EmptyStartRoom()
other_room = ChestRoomKey1()
```

From the code above I get:

You are now in Room #1

You are now in Room #2

Comment: Why would you want to avoid using `super()`?

Comment: @Blender I was told there are goods and bads of using super() so as a beginner if I'm not sure what I'm doing I should avoid using it if possible. Maybe that's not the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly call the base class while also passing the `self` argument:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
class Room(object):    
    def __init__(self, current_room):
        self.current_room = current_room
        print("You are now in Room #{}".format(self.current_room))

class EmptyStartRoom(Room):    
    def __init__(self, current_room=1):
        Room.__init__(self, current_room)

class ChestRoomKey1(Room):    
    def __init__(self, current_room=2):
        Room.__init__(self, current_room)

a_room = EmptyStartRoom()
other_room = ChestRoomKey1()
```

You should also check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/222877/6622817) post, telling you why you *should* consider using `super()` when you start doing multi-inheritance, but for now, both ways are fine.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to find alternatives.

They may be possible but you'll end up hardcoding superclasses (see @abccd answer) or using "your own [MRO](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) solution". But avoiding `super()` will turn into a maintenance nightmare in the long run (and it's harder to implement *right now*).

In your case you're doing everything right! The example is a bit weird because the only difference between the `__init__` methods is a default value for an argument but I guess that was just to illustrate the problem, right?