# `self.response_class` in `TemplateResponseMixin` don't call super()

Tags: django

Referencece to `response_class` in Django's code:
[django/base.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/base.py)

```
class TemplateResponseMixin:
    """A mixin that can be used to render a template."""
    response_class = TemplateResponse
   def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
       response_kwargs.setdefault('content_type', self.content_type)
    #here
        return self.response_class(
     #here
            request=self.request,
            template=self.get_template_names(),
            context=context,
            using=self.template_engine,
            **response_kwargs
        )
```

The class attribute setting `response_class = TemplateResponse`,
while call it through instance's attribute `self.response_class`,
I guess it might be `super().response_class`

How to understand it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `super()` when calling superclass's method. But in case of `response_class` it's just attribute defined inside `TemplateResponseMixin` so you can simple accessed it through `self.response_class`. Since `response_class` is `Class` to instancinate you need to add `()` like this: `self.response_class(*args, **kwargs)`.
You can check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222877/what-does-super-do-in-python) to get more details about `super()`.

Example:

```
class A:
    def method_a(self):
        pass

class B(A):
    some_class = SomeClass

    def method_a(self):
        super().method_a() # This code will find A's method_a and call it
        self.some_class() # This will only instancinate some_class attribute of current B's instance
```