# Can someone explain me call stack happening in here?It calls D,B,C,A.Can you provide how it happens

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to concept of super.I'm unable to understand the call stack made by m method of each class in this code

```
class A:
    def m(self):
        print("m of A called")
        print("OUT OF A")

class B(A):
    def m(self):
        print("m of B called")
        super().m()
        print("OUT OF B")

class C(A):
    def m(self):
        print("m of C called")
        super().m()
        print("OUT OF C")

class D(B,C):
    def m(self):
        print("m of D called")
        super().m()
        print("OUT OF D")

x = D()
x.m()
```

Output of following is:

```
m of D called
m of B called
m of C called
m of A called
OUT OF A
OUT OF C
OUT OF B
OUT OF D
```

How is super from D calling B.() and C.() which calls A.m() only once

Comment: A must watch: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiOglTERPEo

Comment: I suggest that you read this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33469090/8944855

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The explanation can be found here: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#super

Basically you get the EITHER the super class or sibling (with multiple inheritance)

from the link:

> The second use case is to support cooperative multiple inheritance in
>   a dynamic execution environment. This use case is unique to Python and
>   is not found in statically compiled languages or languages that only
>   support single inheritance. This makes it possible to implement
>   “diamond diagrams” where multiple base classes implement the same
>   method. Good design dictates that this method have the same calling
>   signature in every case (because the order of calls is determined at
>   runtime, because that order adapts to changes in the class hierarchy,
>   and because that order can include sibling classes that are unknown
>   prior to runtime).