# Inheriting from `matplotlib.patches.RegularPolygon` yields `ValueError` on instantiation

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to derive a class from `matplotlib.patches.RegularPolygon`.
The immediate aim is to have a somewhat unified API for `matplotlib.patches.Circle` and `matplotlib.patches.RegularPolygon` (they differ in some of their properties), which I can then use in the rest of my application. As all of the code is written for `Circle` so far, it makes sense to modify the properties of `RegularPolygon`.

However, for some reason, arguments are not passed through correctly -- at least that is my best explanation so far. I could use some pointers why that is the case. I have stared at the source code ([link](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/932fd814f2de10fa767f47295915c3625f920f5e/lib/matplotlib/patches.py#L787)) for a long time and don't see it (potentially because I am looking in the wrong place).

## MWE

```
import matplotlib

class RegularPolygon(matplotlib.patches.RegularPolygon):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(matplotlib.patches.RegularPolygon, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

RegularPolygon((0.,0.), 5, radius=5, orientation=0)
```

## Error message

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-1189a0acbaf3> in <module>()
----> 1 RegularPolygon((0.,0.), 5, radius=5, orientation=0)

<ipython-input-3-3cc2c77e24bf> in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
      6
      7     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
----> 8         super(matplotlib.patches.RegularPolygon, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

/home/paul/.virtualenvs/base2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/patches.pyc in __init__(self, edgecolor, facecolor, color, linewidth, linestyle, antialiased, hatch, fill, capstyle, joinstyle, **kwargs)
     93             self.set_color(color)
     94         else:
---> 95             self.set_edgecolor(edgecolor)
     96             self.set_facecolor(facecolor)
     97         # unscaled dashes.  Needed to scale dash patterns by lw

/home/paul/.virtualenvs/base2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/patches.pyc in set_edgecolor(self, color)
    282         """
    283         self._original_edgecolor = color
--> 284         self._set_edgecolor(color)
    285
    286     def set_ec(self, color):

/home/paul/.virtualenvs/base2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/patches.pyc in _set_edgecolor(self, color)
    270                 set_hatch_color = False
    271
--> 272         self._edgecolor = colors.to_rgba(color, self._alpha)
    273         if set_hatch_color:
    274             self._hatch_color = self._edgecolor

/home/paul/.virtualenvs/base2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/colors.pyc in to_rgba(c, alpha)
    132         rgba = _colors_full_map.cache[c, alpha]
    133     except (KeyError, TypeError):  # Not in cache, or unhashable.
--> 134         rgba = _to_rgba_no_colorcycle(c, alpha)
    135         try:
    136             _colors_full_map.cache[c, alpha] = rgba

/home/paul/.virtualenvs/base2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/colors.pyc in _to_rgba_no_colorcycle(c, alpha)
    187     c = tuple(c.astype(float))
    188     if len(c) not in [3, 4]:
--> 189         raise ValueError("RGBA sequence should have length 3 or 4")
    190     if len(c) == 3 and alpha is None:
    191         alpha = 1

ValueError: RGBA sequence should have length 3 or 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

```
super(matplotlib.patches.RegularPolygon, self).__init__()
```

you calling the init function of the parent of `matplotlib.patches.RegularPolygon`. However you would really need to call the init of `matplotlib.patches.RegularPolygon` itself.

I would also suggest not to use the same name for the subclassed artist, as this might add to confusion here.

Options you have

- Old style

  ```
  import matplotlib

  class MyRegularPolygon(matplotlib.patches.RegularPolygon):
      def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
          matplotlib.patches.RegularPolygon.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

  r = MyRegularPolygon((0.,0.), 5, radius=5, orientation=0)
  ```
- New Style (py2 & 3)

  ```
  import matplotlib

  class MyRegularPolygon(matplotlib.patches.RegularPolygon):
      def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
          super(MyRegularPolygon, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

  r = MyRegularPolygon((0.,0.), 5, radius=5, orientation=0)
  ```
- New Style (only py3)

  ```
  import matplotlib

  class MyRegularPolygon(matplotlib.patches.RegularPolygon):
      def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
          super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

  r = MyRegularPolygon((0.,0.), 5, radius=5, orientation=0)
  ```

I would suggest reading [What does 'super' do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222877/what-does-super-do-in-python) for some explanation of `super`.

Comment: Thanks Ernest. I was being dense, as I suspected. A a normal day, I know how `super` works, I promise!

Comment: * on a normal day. Which this one is not. Clearly.

Comment: Don't forget that one of the many possible steps for debugging is "get some fresh air" or "look at it again tomorrow". :-)