# When to call super(..) and when not to?

Tags: python, inheritance, polymorphism

I have a simple question regarding the programming style/convention in python when it comes to superclasses, and calling their methods.

Lets assume I have

```
class A():
  def a(self):
    print "a"
```

and I have another class, class B. Is it better to do :-

```
class B(A):
  pass
```

vs

```
class B(A):
  def a(self):
    super(B,self).a()
```

I eventually want to do :  `b = B(); b.a()`
Is there any difference in the two, except for readability?

Comment: This is a duplicated question. please refer to [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222877/what-does-super-do-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222877/what-does-super-do-in-python)

Comment: @WongSiwei I don't ask what super does. I ask when I should use it. What are the scenarios in which super *should* be used and what are the scenarios that I can skip out on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `super` when an overriding method should do something *in addition* to what its base class's method is doing.

For example, if you have `class Point` and `class Circle(Point)` and want to implement `def move`, circles can just reuse point's method they inherit - since moving a circle is precisely moving the circle's centre point.

But if you have `class Monster` and `class Dragon(Monster)`... you might want to scorch the land when a dragon walks past, that other monsters would not do. So you'd say that dragon movement is same as normal movement, with some fire added:

```
class Dragon(Monster):
    def move(self, destination):
        super(Monster, self).move(destination)
        destination.add_some_fire()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't changing or extending the functionality of the parent method, then there's no reason to even define it - let alone override it. If you don't define it, then the parent method will be used.