# Parent method being overwritten by child

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

Let's say we have:

```
class Parent():
    def __init__(self):
        foo()

    def foo(self):
        //do stuff

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        Parent.__init__()

class Grandchild(Child):
    def __init__(self):
        Child.__init__()

    def foo(self):
        //different stuff
```

There are a lot of classes at the `Child` level that use the same `foo()`. `Grandchild` level has a slightly different version of `foo`, but when `Grandchild` is initiated, the `foo()` call in `Parent.__init__()` uses the `Parent.foo()` instead of `Grandchild.foo()`.

Is there a correct practice when in comes to this kind of situation?

Comment: We need to see a [mcve]. Your code has a lot of bugs, and I don't just mean the `//do stuff`. Normally, you *would* end up calling `Grandchild.foo` (which would be its own source of bugs because `Grandchild.foo` probably assumes `self` is initialized).

Comment: read about `super()` when you are at it - see [What does super do in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222877/what-does-super-do-in-python)

Comment: Read about [Class Inheritance](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm)

Comment: FWIW, in Python comments start with a `#` not `//`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not calling the base classes' `__init__()` methods properly—you need to pass along the `self` argument to them:

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo()

    def foo(self):
        print('Parent stuff')

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        Parent.__init__(self)

class Grandchild(Child):
    def __init__(self):
        Child.__init__(self)

    def foo(self):
        print('Grandchild stuff')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    gc = Grandchild()  # -> Grandchild stuff
```

If you use `super()` instead of explicitly stating the base class, you don't have to do that:

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo()

    def foo(self):
        print('Parent stuff')

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
#        Parent.__init__(self)
        super().__init__()

class Grandchild(Child):
    def __init__(self):
#        Child.__init__(self)
        super().__init__()

    def foo(self):
        print('Grandchild stuff')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    gc = Grandchild()  # -> Grandchild stuff
```

Another advantage is that you likely wouldn't have to change the code in a subclass' `__init__()` method if you changed its base class.

Comment: While this is true, omitting `self` in the superclass constructor calls would lead to a TypeError, not to calling `Parent.foo`.

Comment: @user2357112: Not sure what point you're trying to make. I never said that leaving it out would call `Parent.foo`. THe problem with the OP's code is it doesn't construct the subclasses properly—the `__init__()` method is both of them doesn't call their superclass' `__init__()` because it's coded wrong. The code in the OP's question is somewhat misleading in the sense that it's not run-able (as well as not not properly calling super class `__init__()` methods).

Comment: The question says "when Grandchild is initiated, the foo() call in Parent.__init__() uses the Parent.foo() instead of Grandchild.foo()", which doesn't really make sense and needs a better code sample. You've addressed the lack of `self` in the constructor calls, but that seems to be an artifact of the questioner making up the code snippet. Your answer doesn't have anything in it related to which version of `foo` gets called, which seems to be the core of the question.

Comment: I think the content of your post is true, but not an answer to the question. The question doesn't seem to be answerable in its current state, and I believe it should be closed.

Comment: @user2357112: In my opinion it answers the question because it shows that the whole problem is with how the code was written—and if the subclass `__init__()` methods are written properly, then instances will start behaving the way the OP desires/expects.