# What happens when super() contains the class it is written inside, as a parameter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, inheritance, super

In this instance, what is being accomplished by the super function?

```
    class A(object):
        def __init__(self, <args>):
            super(A, self).__init__()
```

The other questions on StackOverflow involve a Base class that inherits from a parent class. In this particular question, `class A` has a parameter `object` (default object, as per Python 2.7 syntax), and the `__init__()` function has a `super` call referring to the `___init__()` method of `object`(?). Since `object` is a default notation, what does this code mean? What exactly is being called when there is no parent class declared?

Comment: It is calling the superclass `__init__()`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222877/what-does-super-do-in-python/51388706#51388706