# What does super achieve

Tags: python, keras-layer

This is the code for building custom keras layer

```
class MyLayer(Layer):

    def __init__(self, output_dim, **kwargs):
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        super(MyLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

what is super doing here and is it absolutely necessary ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does 'super' do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222877/what-does-super-do-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow. Super -

```
“.. returns a proxy object that delegates method calls to a parent or sibling class of type. This is useful for accessing inherited methods that have been overridden in a class. The search order is same as that used by getattr() except that the type itself is skipped.”
```

Specifically in the case of Keras, the base Layer performs all the base actions for the class, as in the source code,

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/base_layer.py#L21

You could read more about Super and Inheritance at

https://realpython.com/python-super/