# How to change the text on different labels from the same TextInput field?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

In my program I have a button that adds a new box. When you press a button in this new box it adds a new box, and so on. In each box I have a label, and I want to be able to change this text from the same textinput field. But I dont want the same text in each box, so I want to select the box, write the text, and then press a button so that the text is passed from the input field to that specific box/label. I have removed everything else from my app, so I will show you a complete code so you can try the program to understand what I mean.

I have tried to use a button on the main widget, but then I dont know how to choose which box that should be updated. I have also tried to use a button in the box (called "R" in the code), but then I only gets an error.

If i use the code that is commented out i get this error:

```
"AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'"
```

I would really appreciate some help! Thanks a lot.

#### This is the python file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout


class Home(FloatLayout):

    def first(self, *args):
        a = box()
        self.ids.frame.add_widget(a)
        b = a.ids.btn3
        b.bind(on_press=self.second)
        c = a.ids.btn1
        c.bind(on_press=self.textedit)

    def second(self, *args):
        d = box()
        e = d.ids.mains
        e.pos_hint={"right": .5, "top": .7}
        self.ids.frame.add_widget(d)
        f = d.ids.btn3
        f.bind(on_press=self.third)
        g = d.ids.btn1
        g.bind(on_press=self.textedit)

    def third(self, *args):
        h = box()
        i = h.ids.mains
        i.pos_hint = {"right": .3, "top": .9}
        self.ids.frame.add_widget(h)
        j = h.ids.btn1
        j.bind(on_press=self.textedit)

    def textedit(self, *args):
        print("Hello")
       #k = self.ids.tinput.text
       #l = self.ids.lab
       #l.text = k

    def textedit2(self, *args):
        print("hei")
       #This is the submitbutton on the main widget

class HiApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Home()

class box(FloatLayout):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    HiApp().run()
```

#### This is the .kv file

```
<Home>:
    FloatLayout:
        id: frame
        size_hint_y: 1
        pos_hint:{"right":1,"top":1}
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: (1, 1, 1, 1)
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos

    BoxLayout:
        id: boks
        orientation: "vertical"
        size_hint_x: .20
        size_hint_y: .15
        pos_hint:{"right":1,"top":1}
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: (0, 1, 0, 1)
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        TextInput:
            id: tinput
            hint_text: "Frome here"

        Button:
            id: t_sub
            text: "Submit"
            on_press: root.textedit2()

    Button:
        id: start
        text: "Start"
        font_size: 20
        color: 0, 0, 0, 1
        background_normal: ''
        background_color: .88, .88, .88, 1
        size_hint: .1, .1
        pos_hint:{"right":.5,"top":.35}
        on_press: root.first()

<box>:

    BoxLayout:
        id: mains
        orientation: "vertical"
        size_hint_x: .18
        size_hint_y: .13
        pos_hint:{"right":.3,"top":.5}
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: (.20, .05, .0, 1)
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos

        BoxLayout:
            id: c1
            size_hint_y: .25
            pos_hint:{"left":.1,"top":.5}

            GridLayout:
                rows: 1
                cols: 3
                padding: 4
                spacing: 4

                Button:
                    id: btn1
                    text: "R"
                    font_size: 30
                    color: 0, 0, 0, 1
                    background_normal: ''
                    background_color: .88, .88, .88, 1
                    size_hint: .3, .3
                    pos_hint:{"left":.5,"top":.5}
                    on_press:

                Button:
                    id: btn2
                    text: "-"
                    font_size: 30
                    color: 1, 0, 0, 1
                    background_normal: ''
                    background_color: .88, .88, .88, 1
                    size_hint: .3, .3
                    pos_hint:{"left":.5,"top":.5}
                    on_press:

                Button:
                    id: btn3
                    text: "+"
                    font_size: 30
                    color: 0, 1, 0, 1
                    background_normal: ''
                    background_color: .88, .88, .88, 1
                    size_hint: .3, .3
                    pos_hint:{"left":.5,"top":.5}
                    on_press:

        GridLayout:
            rows: 1
            cols: 2
            padding: 4
            spacing: 4

            Label:
                id: lab
                text: "Text here"

            TextInput:
                hint_text: "0"
```

Comment: are you meaning to call `super(FloatLayout, self).__init__`? This calls `FloatLayout`s base class' `__init__` rather than `FloatLayout`s `__init__`..

Comment: I dont know. I am struggling to understand "__init__" and "super"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222877/what-does-super-do-in-python this should help. If you are in python3, just call super() without arguments and that just refers you to the base class

Comment: @Nick: Do you want the Label's text to change after finished typing in TextInput of box2 and pressing Enter key?

Comment: i want to write the text in the inputfield whit the id: tinput (upper left corner) and then pres the button (R) so that the text goes from the inputfield to the label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem

> I want to write the text in the inputfield with the `id: tinput`
>   (upper left corner) and then press the button (R) so that the text
>   goes from the inputfield to the label.

## Solution

The solution to is use the following keywords in kv file:

1. `app` - always refers to the instance of your application
2. `root` - refers to the base widget/template in the current rule

### Snippets - kv file

```
            Button:
                id: btn1
                text: "R"
                font_size: 30
                color: 0, 0, 0, 1
                background_normal: ''
                background_color: .88, .88, .88, 1
                size_hint: .3, .3
                pos_hint:{"left":.5,"top":.5}
                on_press:
                    lab.text = app.root.ids.tinput.text
```

## Output

[image: Entered text]
[image: Box's Label's text changed]

Comment: Ah! I did not know about this. Thanks! But i want to write the text in the other TexInput, ID: tinput