# Why do we not need to include self in super()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, initialization, super

Why in `super()` keyword, can we omit `self`?
What if we don't omit it?

```py
class A:
  def __init__(self, var1, var2):
    """
    some code
    """

class B(A):
  def __init__(self, varA, varB):
    super().__init__(varA, varB)
    """
    some code
    """
```

Comment: Similar question with terrible answer: [Python: super and \_\_init\_\_() vs \_\_init\_\_( self )](//stackoverflow.com/q/7629556)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does 'super' do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222877/what-does-super-do-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, length, width):
    self.length = length
    self.width = width

    def area(self):
    return self.length * self.width

    def perimeter(self):
    return 2 * self.length + 2 * self.width

class Square(Rectangle):
    def __init__(self, length):
        super(Square, self).__init__(length, length)
```

In Python 3, the super(Square, self) call is equivalent to the parameterless super() call. The first parameter refers to the subclass Square, while the second parameter refers to a Square object which, in this case, is self. You can call super() with other classes as well:

```
class Cube(Square):
def surface_area(self):
    face_area = super(Square, self).area()
    return face_area * 6

def volume(self):
    face_area = super(Square, self).area()
    return face_area * self.length
```

[You can find more details here](https://realpython.com/python-super/)