# I can't pass parent variables through Tkinter in Python 2.7

Tags: python, inheritance, tkinter

First of All, I have to say that I am a beginner in Python, so my code might appears redundant or muddled.
I made this code which consists of two classes that are both tkinter frame. The class `ExportGUI` inherits from `Hdf5GUI` and is called by the function `export`. The thing is I am trying to access the parent variable `datasetsfilter` through a child function but it doesnt work :

```
# Parent class

class Hdf5GUI(GUI):

    def __init__(self,hdf5w,master):

        # Frame definition
        self.master = master # parent root
        self.hdf5w = hdf5w #root
        self.hdf5w.title('Hdf5 Reader') 
        self.hdf5w.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.hdf5w.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.hdf5w.columnconfigure(1,weight=1)

        self.frameDataset = Frame(self.hdf5w,padx=5,pady=5)
        self.frameDataset.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='wesn')
        self.frameDataset.rowconfigure(1,weight=1)
        self.frameDataset.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

        self.datasetpath_button = Button(self.frameDataset,text="Export dataset path",command = self.exportDatasetPath)
        self.datasetpath_button.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=2,pady=5,sticky='nwe')

        self.dataset_scrollbar = Scrollbar(self.frameDataset)
        self.dataset_scrollbar.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky='esn')

        self.dataset_listbox = Listbox(self.frameDataset,exportselection=0)
        self.dataset_listbox.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky='wesn')
        self.dataset_listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.onSelectDataset)

        self.dataset_listbox.config(yscrollcommand=self.dataset_scrollbar.set)
        self.dataset_scrollbar.config(command=self.dataset_listbox.yview)

        self.datatype_scrollbar = Scrollbar(self.frameDataset)
        self.datatype_scrollbar.grid(row=2,column=1,sticky='esn')

        self.datatype_listbox = Listbox(self.frameDataset,selectmode='extended',exportselection=0)
        self.datatype_listbox.grid(row=2,column=0,sticky='wesn')
#        self.dataset_listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.onSelectDataset)
#        
        self.datatype_listbox.config(yscrollcommand=self.datatype_scrollbar.set)
        self.datatype_scrollbar.config(command=self.datatype_listbox.yview)        



        self.frameFilter = Frame(self.frameDataset)
        self.frameFilter.grid(row=3,column=0,sticky='wen')
        self.frameFilter.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.frameFilter.columnconfigure(1,weight=1)
        self.frameFilter.columnconfigure(2,weight=1)
        self.frameFilter.columnconfigure(3,weight=1)

        self.filter_label = Label(self.frameFilter,text="Dataset filter")
        self.filter_label.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=4,sticky='wen')

        self.filter0 = Listbox(self.frameFilter,exportselection=0)
        self.filter0.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky='wen')
        self.filter0.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.onSelectFilter0)

        self.filter1 = Listbox(self.frameFilter,exportselection=0)
        self.filter1.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky='wen')
        self.filter1.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.onSelectFilter1)

        self.filter2 = Listbox(self.frameFilter,exportselection=0)
        self.filter2.grid(row=1,column=2,sticky='wen')
        self.filter2.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.onSelectFilter2)

        self.filter3 = Listbox(self.frameFilter,exportselection=0)
        self.filter3.grid(row=1,column=3,sticky='wen')

        self.frameFile = Frame(self.hdf5w,padx=5,pady=5)
        self.frameFile.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky='wesn')
        self.frameFile.rowconfigure(1,weight=1)
        self.frameFile.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

        self.folderPath_button = Button(self.frameFile,text="Open files in directory",command=self.exportFiles)
        self.folderPath_button.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=2,pady=5,sticky='wen')

        self.files_listbox = Listbox(self.frameFile,selectmode='extended',exportselection=0)
        self.files_listbox.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky='wesn')

        self.files_scrollbar = Scrollbar(self.frameFile)
        self.files_scrollbar.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky='esn')

        self.files_listbox.config(yscrollcommand=self.files_scrollbar.set)
        self.files_scrollbar.config(command=self.files_listbox.yview)

        self.displayData_button = Button(self.frameFile, text="display dataset", command=self.displayData)
        self.displayData_button.grid(row=2,column=0,columnspan=2,padx=10,pady=5,sticky='wen')


        self.displayTxt_button = Button(self.frameFile, text="Export", command=self.export)
        self.displayTxt_button.grid(row=2,column=1,columnspan=2,padx=10,pady=5,sticky='wen')



#        self.lblFrame = LabelFrame()


        self.hdf5w.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.onClosing)





        self.hdf5w.mainloop()

    def exportDatasetPath(self):

        self.dataset_listbox.delete(0,'end')
        self.filter0.delete(0,'end')
        self.filter1.delete(0,'end')
        self.filter2.delete(0,'end')
        self.filter3.delete(0,'end')

        self.ohdf5 = Hdf5()

        print(self.ohdf5.loadcase_label_list)

        i = 0
        for dataset in self.ohdf5.datasets:
            self.dataset_listbox.insert(i,dataset)
            i+=1

        i = 0
        for item in self.ohdf5.filter0:
            self.filter0.insert(i,item)
            i+=1

    def onSelectDataset(self,evt):

        self.datatype_listbox.delete(0,'end')
        index = self.dataset_listbox.curselection()[0]
        datasetPath = self.dataset_listbox.get(index)

        self.odataset = self.ohdf5.getDataset(datasetPath)

        i=0
        for col in self.odataset.columns:
            self.datatype_listbox.insert(i,col)
            i+=1


    def onSelectFilter0(self,evt):

        self.dataset_listbox.delete(0,'end')
        self.filter1.delete(0,'end')
        self.filter2.delete(0,'end')
        self.filter3.delete(0,'end')

        index = self.filter0.curselection()[0]
        item0 = self.filter0.get(index)


        if item0 == 'NASTRAN':
            i = 0
            for dataset in self.ohdf5.datasets:
                self.dataset_listbox.insert(i,dataset)
                i+=1

        else:

            self.ohdf5.setFilterGroupPath(item0)
            self.ohdf5.setFilterGroup(self.ohdf5.filterGroupPath)

            i = 0
            self.datasetsfilter = self.ohdf5.getDatasets(self.ohdf5.filterGroupPath)
            for dataset in self.datasetsfilter:
                self.dataset_listbox.insert(i,dataset)
                i+=1

            i = 0
            for item in self.ohdf5.filter1:
                self.filter1.insert(i,item)
                i+=1

    def onSelectFilter1(self,evt):

        self.dataset_listbox.delete(0,'end')
        self.filter2.delete(0,'end')
        self.filter3.delete(0,'end')

        index = self.filter0.curselection()[0]
        item0 = self.filter0.get(index)
        index = self.filter1.curselection()[0]
        item1 = self.filter1.get(index)

        self.ohdf5.setFilterGroupPath(item0,item1)
        self.ohdf5.setFilterGroup(self.ohdf5.filterGroupPath)

        i = 0
        self.datasetsfilter = self.ohdf5.getDatasets(self.ohdf5.filterGroupPath)
        print(self.datasetsfilter)
        for dataset in self.datasetsfilter:
            self.dataset_listbox.insert(i,dataset)
            i+=1

        i = 0
        for item in self.ohdf5.filter2:
            self.filter2.insert(i,item)
            i+=1

    def onSelectFilter2(self,evt):

        self.dataset_listbox.delete(0,'end')
        self.filter3.delete(0,'end')

        index = self.filter0.curselection()[0]
        item0 = self.filter0.get(index)
        index = self.filter1.curselection()[0]
        item1 = self.filter1.get(index)
        index = self.filter2.curselection()[0]
        item2 = self.filter2.get(index)

        self.ohdf5.setFilterGroupPath(item0,item1,item2)
        self.ohdf5.setFilterGroup(self.ohdf5.filterGroupPath)

        i = 0
        self.datasetsfilter = self.ohdf5.getDatasets(self.ohdf5.filterGroupPath)
        print(self.datasetsfilter)
        for dataset in self.datasetsfilter:
            self.dataset_listbox.insert(i,dataset)
            i+=1

        i = 0
        for item in self.ohdf5.filter3:
            self.filter3.insert(i,item)
            i+=1

    def exportFiles(self):

        self.files_listbox.delete(0,'end')

        title = 'Choose the working HDF5 directory where there are *.h5 files :'
        Tk().withdraw()
        dirname_root = askdirectory(initialdir=os.getcwd(), title = title)

        self.filePath_list = []

        for folders, subfolders,files in os.walk(dirname_root):
            for f in files:
                ext = os.path.splitext(f)[1]
                if ext == '.h5': self.filePath_list.append(os.path.join(folders,f))

        i = 0
        for path in self.filePath_list:
            self.files_listbox.insert(i,os.path.basename(path))
            i+=1

    def onClosing(self):

#        if tkMessageBox.askokcancel("Quit", "Do you want to quit?"):
        self.hdf5w.destroy()
        self.show(self.master)  

    def displayData(self):
        print('function dislaying datas')
        datas =   self.datatype_listbox.curselection()
        print(datas)
        new_window = Toplevel(self.frameFile)
        w = DisplayDataGUI(new_window, self.odataset, datas)

    def get_datasetsfilter(self):
        return self.datasetsfilter

    def export(self):
        new_window2 = Toplevel(self.frameFile)
        w = ExportGUI(self.hdf5w,new_window2)
```

So until now my code perfectly works but I had to complete my program with some other functions that I call in `ExportGUI`. For example `export_filter`.

```
#==============================================================================
# Child class   
#==============================================================================



class ExportGUI(Hdf5GUI): 

    def __init__(self,hdf5w, master):

        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Export")
        self.master.geometry('200x200')

        label = Label(self.master, text="Choose the kind of export")
        label.place(x=20, y=0)

        export_selected = Button(self.master, text = 'Export filters',command=self.export_filter)
        export_selected.place(x=20, y=50)

        self.master.mainloop()   

    def export_filter(self):    
        print(self.ohdf5.datatsetsfilter)
```

But I got the following error :

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1542, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "GUI\GUI.py", line 397, in export_filter
    print(self.ohdf5.datatsetsfilter)
AttributeError: 'ExportGUI' object has no attribute 'ohdf5'
```

Neither `ohdf5` or `datatsetsfilter` is known by `ExportGUI`(I had the same error with `self.datatsetsfilter`). 
**Considering this code didnt work** I tried to use the `super` function. I created a function `get_datasetsfilter` in `Hdf5GUI` :

```
 def get_datasetsfilter(self):
        return self.datasetsfilter
```

and then called it in `ExportGUI` (I added `__metaclass__ = type` to fix type prblm in 2.7) :

```
def export_filter(self):    
        super(ExportGUI, self).get_datasetsfilter
```

I admit I saw many other exemple with `Super` but they all seems to be used in `__init__` method. However, it still doesnt work. I am now wondering if the error results from my bad comprehension of inheritance or `tkinter`.

Comment: Where would you think `ohdf5` is defined? Perhaps you're missing a call to `super().__init__()`?

Comment: @deceze♦ Note that my entire parent class perfectly works and that `self.ohdf5 = Hdf5()`, I dont really know how to use `super()` could you explain it to me?

Comment: Post your complete code, the important part where you initialize objects and usage.

Comment: Your code and error message are incompatible with each other. Show the code in a state where it produces the error.

Comment: @blues Sorry i mixed up between my tries. But I modifed the code to match the code error

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have overwritten the `__init__` method from the parent class. Usually what you is first call the `__init__` method from the parent class that can be accessed using the [super()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222877/what-does-super-do-in-python). So your code should be something like:

```
class ExportGUI(Parent_Class):

    def __init__(self, hdf5w, master):
        super().__init__(hdf5w, master)
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Export")
        self.master.geometry('200x200')
```

**UPDATE:**

Now that you've cleared certain details I can augment this answer. Notice that the `__init__` call from the `ExportGUI` is now called with two passed arguments, namely `hdf5w` and `master`, the first one is needed to successfully call the `__init__` from the parent class. Thus you need to change the code in the definiton of `Parent_Class` where you're creating an instance of `ExportGUI`, so that a proper value for hdf5w will be passed in -- my guess would be, you want to pass the value from the parent class:

```
def export(self):
    new_window2 = Toplevel(self.frameFile)
    w = ExportGUI(self.hdf5w, new_window2)
```

And I can't help but notice, that the arguments passed to `Parent_Class.__init__` namely `hdf5w` and `master` are not used anywhere. Maybe you want to either save those in variables, for example:

```
class Parent_Class(GUI):

    def __init__(self,hdf5w,master):
        self.hdf5w = hdf5w
        self.master = master
```

If those are the same and should be carried across to the `ExportGUI` they can be simply passed when you're creating an instance in the `export` function of the `Parent_Class`. If you don't need them and decide to remove them, make sure to modify the `__init__` call of the `Parent_Class` as well as the `super().__init__` call in the `ExportGUI`.

Comment: This won't be enough: not only `Extended_Class` but also `Parent_Class` has to call its inherited `__init__()`.

Comment: You're right, the __init__() gets overwritten there as well. However, his problem was specific and apparently calling Parent_Class.ohdf5 works as expected.

Comment: @Schmuddi So i modified my code but I got a code error because of `ExportGUI(new_window2)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)` what should I fill in?

Comment: What error did you get? Did you read about inheritance and how to use super()?

Comment: I got the error code that I just mentionned above. Sorry I didnt see your link to `super` doc. I'll read it and comeback after.

Comment: Where is `ExportGUI()` defined? Should it maybe be `self.ExportGUI(new_window2)`?

Comment: That is the problem when you change variables name to make code more cleaner. `ExportGUI` is what I called here `Extended_Class`.

Comment: Ok, please update your question. I'll update my answer accordingly as well.