# Python: Calling Inherited Parent Class Method Fails

Tags: python, pandas, oop, scikit-learn

I created a pass-through wrapper class around an existing class from `sklearn` and it does not behave as expected:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder

tiny_df = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['a', 'b']})

class Foo(OrdinalEncoder):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        super().fit(X, y)
        return self


oe = OrdinalEncoder()
oe.fit(tiny_df) # works fine
foo = Foo()
foo.fit(tiny_df) # fails
```

The relevant part of the error message I receive is:

```
~\.conda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_encoders.py in _fit(self, X, handle_unknown)
     69                         raise ValueError("Unsorted categories are not "
     70                                          "supported for numerical categories")
---> 71             if len(self._categories) != n_features:
     72                 raise ValueError("Shape mismatch: if n_values is an array,"
     73                                  " it has to be of shape (n_features,).")

TypeError: object of type 'Foo' has no len()
```

Somehow parent's private property `_categories` does not seem to get set, even though I've called the parent constructor in the `__init__()` method of my class. I must be missing something simple here, and would appreciate any help!

Comment: do you also need to pass *args to the constructor?

Comment: I added `*args` in calls to both `__init__()` methods, and that did not change the error I'm getting.

Comment: There is a `__len__` magicmethod that you can implement.

Comment: I doubt this will solve the problem - I have no idea how `__len__` is implemented in the parent class, and the whole idea of creating a child class is that I wouldn't have to - all the parent methods should _just work_. No?

Comment: The error message implies that `self._categories` is an object of type `Foo`.  I think the problem is with the `self` in the `__init__`.  Change it to `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)`.  The `self` is already included in the `super()`.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222877/what-does-super-do-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to pass `self` again to the `super` function. And `scikit-learn`'s estimators should always specify their parameters in the signature of their `__init__` and no `varargs` are allowed else you will get a `RUNTIMEERROR`, so you have to remove it. I have modified your code as below:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder

tiny_df = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['a', 'b']})

class Foo(OrdinalEncoder):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        super().fit(X, y)
        return self


oe = OrdinalEncoder()
oe.fit(tiny_df) # works fine
foo = Foo()
foo.fit(tiny_df) # works fine too
```

> SAMPLE OUTPUT

```
foo.transform(tiny_df)
array([[0.],
       [1.]])
```

> A little extra

```
class Foo(OrdinalEncoder):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        super().fit(X, y)
        return self
```

And when you create `Foo`:

```
foo= Foo()

RuntimeError: scikit-learn estimators should always specify their parameters in the signature of their __init__ (no varargs). <class '__main__.Foo'> with constructor (self, *args, **kwargs) doesn't  follow this convention.
```