# How to get a class to inherit its parent's values in Python?

Tags: python, class, inheritance

Here is a rough idea of what I want to do:

```
class PlayerModel(Timeline):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

        self.timeline_min = super(timeline_min)     # I don't know the syntax for this
        self.timeline_max = super(timeline_max)     # I don't know the syntax for this


class Timeline:
    def __init__(self):
        self.timeline_min = 0
        self.timeline_max = 120

    def make_model(self, m_name):
        return PlayerModel(m_name)
```

I want `PlayerModel` to have the same properties from `Timeline` which are:

```
self.timeline_min = 0
self.timeline_max = 120
```

in it's `__init__`, without having to pass them as parameters. Could I achieve this using `super()`? I could not find a way to do this with the parent's variables.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does 'super' do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222877/what-does-super-do-in-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should let `Timeline` set them by calling its `__init__`:

```
class PlayerModel(Timeline):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__()
        self.name = name
```

Unless you explicitly call the parent constructor in the child `__init__` method, Python just assumes you just want to override the parent constructor instead.

Comment: This works, but is there any way I can do this with `super()` but only for specific variables from `Timeline`? Say I had a bunch of variables in `Timeline` but only want `PlayerModel` to inheret `timeline_min` and `timeline_max`. As far as I know this inherits all variables from the parent class

Comment: @pylab The short answer is no. Usually that only makes sense if the parent `__init__` takes arguments. Otherwise you would be constructing an object in a way the super class doesn't support. You can change the variables after you call the super method if you want.