# How to inherit multiple queryset filters via mixins

Tags: django, django-models, django-managers

I have a `QuerySetMixin` in a model manager:

models.py:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    objects = SoftDeletableManager()
```

managers.py:

```
class SoftDeletableManager(SoftDeletableManagerMixin, models.Manager):
    pass

class SoftDeletableQuerySet(QuerySet):
    pass

class SoftDeletableManagerMixin:
    _queryset_class = SoftDeletableQuerySet

    def get_queryset(self):
         return self._queryset_class(
             model=self.model, 
             using=self._db,
             **kwargs).filter(is_removed=False)
```

I want to define a second `QuerySetMixin` that inheits the results of the `SoftDeletableManagerMixin` and filters them. How do I do this?

E.g.

```
class MyManagerMixin:

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.[inherit other querysets].filter(mynewfilter=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inherit it, you might want to use the [**`super()`** proxy object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/222877/67579):

```
class SoftDeletableManagerMixin:
    _queryset_class = SoftDeletableQuerySet

    def get_queryset(self):
         return super().get_queryset().filter(is_removed=False)
```

the same for your second mixin:

```
class MyManagerMixin:

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(mynewfilter=True)
```

You can then make a manager with:

```
class MyNewManager(MyManagerMixin, SoftDeletableManagerMixin, Manager):
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks. In this example wouldn't `super()` override the `_queryset_class`?

Comment: @alias51: no. The method will simply fetch the `._queryset_class` attribute. Since the MRO will put `SoftDeletableManagerMixin` before the `Manager`, it will thus resolve to `SoftDeletableQuerySet`.

Comment: Is there a reason why the Django source code doesn't use this method? It would seem a lot simpler (https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/manager.py#L139)

Comment: @alias51: because that is the first time it defines `get_queryset`, so there is no `get_queryset` method yet in the `super()` proxy :)

Comment: Yes, not enough coffee!! How would I filter on `self.request.user` in a Manger mixin? Is this possible as `def get_queryset(self)` doesn't return an object with attribute `request`...?

Comment: @alias51: no, managers are "request-unaware". You can of course make a method in your manager/queryset that takes a parameter for the request. But you can use models/managers/... without a request (for example a management task), and thus there is not *per se* even a request.

Comment: Where would I pull the `request` from? Is there a method for  `self` under `get_queryset`?

Comment: @alias51: no, you could for example make an extra method `def extra_filtering(self, request): ...`.