# Why `super()` in Ursina module in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, python-import, init

I imported the `Ursina` module to `python`. *`Ursina` is game engine*. You can find it here : [Ursina Game Engine](https://www.ursinaengine.org/)

I was trying to learn how to use this module from the tutorials given on the website itself. I am unable to understand this part of the code. Can anyone please explain this:

```
from ursina import *

class Inventory(Entity):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(
            parent = camera.ui,
            model = 'quad',
             scale = (.5, .8),                                           
             origin = (-.5, .5),                                         
             position = (-.3,.4),                                        
             texture = 'white_cube',                                     
             texture_scale = (5,8),                                      
             color = color.dark_gray                                     
            )



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Ursina()
    inventory = Inventory()
    app.run()
```

These are my specific questions:

---

1. What is `super()`?
2. Why are the functionalities of `super()` class?
3. What is the purpose of the condition `if __name__ == '__main__':`

---

@pokepeter
P.S. Tutorials of Ursina Game Engine has a lot of **typos**, please provide a way to notify the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does 'super' do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222877/what-does-super-do-in-python)

Comment: All three questions have been answered on Stack Overflow several times.