# using super without inheritance class in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

anyone know what it means for following code on `super(xxx, self).__init__()`? what does it do? I though it should be class ABC inherits from other class but I do not see which class is inherited from.

```
class ABC:

    def __init__(self):
        super(ABC, self).__init__()
```

Comment: `ABC` implicitly inherits from `object`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does 'super' do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222877/what-does-super-do-in-python)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`super` works with the method resolution order (MRO) of the class. The MRO *always* contains at least two classes: the class itself, and `object` (because all classes implicitly inherit from `object`)

```
>>> class ABC: pass
...
>>> ABC.__mro__
(<class '__main__.ABC'>, <class 'object'>)
```

If there are any explicitly named base classes in the `class` statement, those and their base classes will appear in the MRO somewhere between the new class and `object`.

```
>>> class ABC(str): pass
...
>>> ABC.__mro__
(<class '__main__.ABC'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'object'>)
```

---

Regarding your question "why `super`?", consider this standard example:

```
class A:
    def foo(self):
        print("A")


class B(A):
    def foo(self):
        super().foo()
        print("B")


class C(A):
    def foo(self):
        super().foo()
        print("C")


class D(B, C):
    def foo(self):
        super().foo()
        print("D")
```

The MRO for `D` is `(D, B, C, A)`. Notice the call `super().foo` in `B.foo`. Looking *only* at the class `B`, you might assume that `super().foo()` is a call to `A.foo`. But when `self` is an instance of `D` (as is the case with `D().foo()`, for example), then `super` refers to `C`, not `A`, because `C` comes immediately after `B` in the MRO.

```
>>> D().foo()
A
C
B
D
```

`foo` outputs the classes in the MRO (*sans* `object`; `A` doesn't use `super` because `A` "introduced" `foo` into the hierarchy) in reverse order, from least to most specific.

Comment: if so, why do i still need super here?

Comment: `super` is primarily used for multiple inheritance; it does not always refer to a class know to `ABC` at compile time.

Comment: `super` *really* should have been given a different name; in Dylan, the equivalent is called `next-method`.

Comment: but why super refer to  `C` and not `B`?

Comment: @tamerlaha Not sure I follow. `super()` refers to *different* classes depending on where it is called. The value used as an implicit first argument is not *statically* determined, but determined by the *runtime* type of `self`. When `self` is an instance of `D`, `super()` in `D.foo` *is* a proxy for `B`. But then in `B.foo`, it is a proxy for `C`.

Answer (score 4):

Classes without explicit bases automatically inherit from `object`. When called via `ABC()`, the `super(ABC, self).__init__()` inside `ABC.__init__` executes `object.__init__`. This can be seen by checking the method resolution order.

```
>>> ABC.__mro__
(__main__.ABC, object)
```

Methods that do nothing but invoke the super method are generally not needed. However, when *adding functionality* it is common to invoke `super` even to refer to `object`.

---

Notably, `super` dispatch is not static, but can change via inheritance. Multiple inheritance can be used to inject another class between `ABC` and `object` in the method resolution order.

```
>>> class Intermediate:
...     def __init__(self):
...         print(f'Intermediate init of {self.__class__.__name__}')
...         super().__init__()
...
>>> class Alphabet(ABC, Intermediate):
...     """Compound of ABC and Intermediate"""
...
>>> Alphabet.__mro__                   # Intermediate is between ABC and object...
(__main__.Alphabet, __main__.ABC, __main__.Intermediate, object)
>>> Alphabet.__init__ is ABC.__init__  # ... but __init__ is still identical!
True
>>> Alphabet()  # Alphabet's ABC.__init__ delegates to Intermediate.__init__ ...
Intermediate init of Alphabet
>>> ABC()       # ... but ABC's ABC.__init__ still does not.
```

A class such as `Intermediate` is generally known as a [mixin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin). In Python, classes intended to be used with mixins must use `super` instead of directly referring to superclass methods.

Answer (score 0):

All classes implicitly inherit from `object`, just like in Java, unless they explicitly inherit from something else (which itself has to either implicitly inherit from `object` or from something else, and so on...).

A byproduct of this is that you can invoke any of `object`'s methods on your object, *ignoring your object's implementation of those methods*, by doing what you've done:

```
>>> dir(object)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__',
 '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__',
 '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
```