# Why save() method has another save() method with super in django model

Tags: django

> I am creating models, where i get bit confusion about save() has another save method with super keyword,  why two save() methods, appreciate for explination.

```
    from django.db import models

    class Blog(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        tagline = models.TextField()

        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            do_something()
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)  # Call the "real" save() method.
            do_something_else()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does 'super' do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222877/what-does-super-do-in-python)

Comment: Read [this](https://realpython.com/inheritance-composition-python/) for example as a good introduction in python object-oriented programming and class inheritance.

Comment: i have knowledge in super method, why its calling two save() methods.

Comment: What do you think `super()` does exactly? Why exactly is `super().save()` confusing to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `save` method which actually does all the database work is defined in `models.Model.save`. Your `Blog` class is overriding the `save` method; when you call `Blog().save()`, it just executes whatever is in your `Blog.save` method. That wouldn't do any of the actual work of writing to the database.

To do something of your devising in your `Blog.save` method **and also run all the code defined in `models.Model.save`**, you need to explicitly call the parent's `save` implementation. Which is what `super().save()` does.

Comment: Nice,  can you disclose in detail about to **models.Model.save**

Comment: ‍♂️ What do you want to know?! Its code?  https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py#L666