# Why is Python super used in the child's init method?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, super

According to [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#super) super()

> is useful for accessing inherited methods that have been overridden in
>   a class.

I understand that super refers to the parent class and it lets you access parent methods. My question is why do people always use super inside the **init** method of the child class? I have seen it everywhere. For example:

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class Employee(Person):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
       super().__init__(name=kwargs['name']) # Here super is being used

    def first_letter(self):
        return self.name[0]

e = Employee(name="John")
print(e.first_letter())
```

I can accomplish the same without super and without even an **init** method:

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class Employee(Person):

    def first_letter(self):
        return self.name[0]

e = Employee(name="John")
print(e.first_letter())
```

Are there drawbacks with the latter code? It looks so much cleanr to me. I don't even have to use the boilerplate **kwargs and kwargs['argument'] syntax.

I am using Python 3.8.
Edit: Here's a[nother stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222877/what-does-super-do-in-python) questions which has code from different people who are using super in the child's init method. I don't understand why. My best guess is there's something new in Python 3.8.

Comment: If you don't define init in child class then it would be inherited from parent class.

Comment: In this case, you don't really need it. The only difference between this implementation and letting `Employee.__init__` resolve to `Person.__init__` is that `kwargs['name']` could raise a `KeyError`.

Comment: Actually, this is worse; it *discards* arguments that may be needed by a class in the MRO that `Person` doesn't know about. *Both* `Person.__init__` and `Child.__init__` should be calling `super().__init__` with `**kwargs`.

Comment: The parent class might also consist of a lot more than just assigning a property (like in your example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The potential drawback to the latter code is that there is no `__init__` method within the Employee class. Since there is none, the `__init__` method of the parent class is called. However, as soon as an `__init__` method is added to the Employee class (maybe there's some Employee-specific attribute that needs to be initialized, like an id_number) then the `__init__` method of the parent class is overridden and not called (unless `super.__init__()` is called) and then an Employee will not have a `name` attribute.

Answer (score 3):

The child might want to do something different or more likely additional to what the super class does - in this case the child must have an `__init__`.

Calling super’s init means that you don’t have to copy/paste (with all the implications for maintenance) that init in the child’s class, which otherwise would be needed if you wanted some additional code in the child init.

But note there are complications about using super’s init if you use multiple inheritance (e.g. which super gets called) and this needs care. Personally I avoid multiple inheritance and keep inheritance to aminimum anyway - it’s easy to get tempted into creating multiple levels of inheritance/class hierarchy but my experience is that a ‘keep it simple’ approach is usually much better.

Comment: When you say "the child may want to do something different or additional to what the super class does" what  exactly do you mean with "something"? Can you give an example or two?

Comment: E.g. the child has an additional attribute that has to be initialised.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to use `super` here is for *both* methods to use `super`. You cannot assume that `Person` is the last (or at least, next-to-last, before `object`) class in the MRO.

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self, name, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.name = name

class Employee(Person):
    # Optional, since Employee.__init__ does nothing
    # except pass the exact same arguments "upstream"
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
       super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def first_letter(self):
        return self.name[0]
```

Consider a class definition like

```
class Bar:
    ...

class Foo(Person, Bar):
    ...
```

The MRO for `Foo` looks like `[Foo, Person, Bar, object]`; the call to `super().__init__` inside `Person.__init__` would call `Bar.__init__`, not `object.__init__`, and `Person` has no way of knowing if values in `**kwargs` are meant for `Bar`, so it *must* pass them on.