# My REST API data is not saving into database but it is returning the correct data

Tags: django, django-serializer

I am very new to Django. I want to store my data to my MYSQL database using a POST request and retrieve the data. However, for some reason, it is not storing to the database but retrieving the correct data.

I am assuming `cust = UserSerializer(data = user_req_data)` line is not valid. How do I fix my code?

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def create(self, validatedData):
        validatedData['password'] = make_password(validatedData['password'])
        #Save to database?

        return validatedData
```

View

```
#User Viewset
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Users.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

Comment: Can youu add your view?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu View is added

Comment: most probably, your cust.is_valid() is not returning true. That's why your cust is not saved. Also, you are returning the user_req_data, not your created instance

Comment: @ArvindKumar I see, I updated my post again. I am wondering how I can save to my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your serializer with this class,

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def create(self, validated_data):
        instance = super().create(validated_data)
        try:
            instance.password = make_password(validated_data['make_password'])
            instance.save()
        except KeyError:
            pass
        return instance
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! Would you mind what super() does? I mean why does super() have the create() method?

Comment: Read this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222877/what-does-super-do-in-python/224020