# what is super in this in this method?

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views, django-generic-views

```
class PublisherDetail(DetailView):

    model = Publisher

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Add in a QuerySet of all the books
        context['book_list'] = Book.objects.all()
        return context
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does 'super' do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222877/what-does-super-do-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

According to the basic Python inheritance rules, `super().get_context_data(...)` would be [`DetailView.get_context_data()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/0be51d2226fce030ac9ca840535a524f41e9832c/django/views/generic/detail.py#L164), but since it's not defined, it's inherited down from [`SingleObjectMixin`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/0be51d2226fce030ac9ca840535a524f41e9832c/django/views/generic/detail.py#L91).