# Why in `super(A, self)` does the object come before the `self`?

Tags: python, super

I am wondering why the syntax for calling the super classes' constructors has the `Child` object passed as an argument before the `self`, and what purpose those arguments serve as to the goal of inheriting the methods of the parent class.

```
class Child(SomeBaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Child, self).__init__()
```

I've read the following posts, but in either have I found the reasoning for this:

1. [The 'super' docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super)
2. [What does 'super' do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222877/what-does-super-do-in-python)
3. In [this post](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=236275) I've found this quote:

   > super(class, subclass).method returned a bound method, not an unbound one

   but still could not get my head around the meaning of this syntax.

Appreciate an elaboration of this syntax.

Comment: Just to be clear: You are asking why the Python language developers decided to use ``super(cls, self)`` instead of ``super(self, cls)``?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by *"why"* (that's the defined order of arguments selected by the Python maintainers: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super), and from a syntax perspective that's just standard function calling either way around.

Comment: The simple answer is *this is what the designers chose*... A more reasonable one is that logically it reads as *the `super` method of class `Child` for object `self`*. Lastly, that's the old way of calling `super` and today you should just call `super()` so your problem is solved

Comment: It is a good question. Usually self comes before a dot, but it is an implicit FIRST argument.So, where self cannot  come before a dot, why is it not FIRST?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, yes. It is unclear to me. Is it only a convention or is there some sort of meaning behind it?

Comment: `self` is only the implicit first argument when you're calling a *method* (bound to the specific instance that's automagically passed as `self`); `super` is a *function*.

Comment: @Tomerikoo thanks for your simple explanation - it really answers my question.

Comment: I was just about to write what jon just said. `super` is a built-in **function**. Hence this order might even be on purpose to distinguish it from a standard instance method and not have people trying `self.super(cls)`

Comment: @jonrsharpe - great explanation! Thanks!

Comment: Note that [the initial idea of ``super``](https://mail.python.org/archives/list/python-dev@python.org/thread/UBHMOZQ6SVBHUOM3KHUMPH3CB7L3GLAI/#5SJ3P7TMPDKF7COB5QF4VQHFCPE55LIU) seems to have been ``super(self, MyBaseClass).foo(arg, ...)``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of `super` arguments reflects Python's idea of unbound and bound methods/descriptors. In short, the second argument is *optional* and thus must come after the required first argument.

> #### Built-in Functions: [super([type[, object-or-type]])](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super)
>
> [...]
>
> If the second argument is omitted, the super object returned is unbound. If the second argument is an object, isinstance(obj, type) must be true. If the second argument is a type, issubclass(type2, type) must be true (this is useful for classmethods).

This reflects how a method call `self.method()` is equivalent to `Class.method(self)`, i.e. the order of operands is `Class` then `self`.`*`

---

Python methods/descriptors come in two flavours: *unbound* on their defining class, and *bound* on their instance.`*`

```py
>>> class Base:
...     def method(self): print('called Base method')
...
>>> Base.method     # unbound method
<function __main__.Base.method(self)>
>>> Base().method   # bound method
<bound method Base.method of <__main__.Base object at 0x10dd0e910>>
>>> Base().method()
called Base method
```

A bound descriptor is created by taking an unbound descriptor and binding it to an instance. This is encoded and implemented in the descriptor protocol.

```py
>>> instance = Base()
>>> unbound = Base.method
>>> unbound.__get__(instance)
<bound method Base.method of <__main__.Base object at 0x10dd14510>>
>>> unbound.__get__(instance)()
called Base method
```

The `super` type is by default unbound. Binding it via the descriptor protocol or by passing an instance is equivalent.

```py
>>> class Child(Base): ...
>>> instance = Child()
>>> super(Child, instance)
<super: __main__.Child, <__main__.Child at 0x10dcda9d0>>
>>> super(Child).__get__(instance)
<super: __main__.Child, <__main__.Child at 0x10dcda9d0>>
```

In either case, *the class must be passed first before the instance*.

---

[From the python-dev archive](https://mail.python.org/archives/list/python-dev@python.org/message/6OESFIX27M7TBHPS56RDD6IKJ772JMET/):

> Add 'super', another new object type with magical properties.
>
> super(type) -> unbound super object
>
> super(type, obj) -> bound super object; requires isinstance(obj, type)
>
> Typical use to call a cooperative superclass method:
>
> ```
> class C(B):
>     def meth(self, arg):
>         super(C, self).meth(arg);
> ```

---

`*` This description glosses over the finer details of the descriptor protocol. For example, a method/descriptor can be bound to a class as well.