# Python: Getting an AttributeError when using parent method on a child class instance (tkinter)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

There's the code I have:

```
import tkinter

class GuiEl(tkinter.Button):
    def __init__(self):
        self = tkinter.Button(rootfr, text = 'Test')
        self.grid(column = 1, row = 1)

    def command_set(self):    
        self.config(command=root.quit)

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title('Test')

rootfr = tkinter.Frame(root)
rootfr.grid(column = 2, row = 2)

button1 = GuiEl()
button1.command_set()

root.mainloop()
```

What I want is to create a class, then make an instance - Button. Then I want to use a method on this instance (actually doesn't matter if it's done using the method of class or directly using the parent method) - `config`, which will modify this instance. What I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "class_try.py", line 18, in <module>
    button1.command_set()
  File "class_try.py", line 9, in command_set
    self.config(command=root.quit)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1485, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1476, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
AttributeError: 'GuiEl' object has no attribute 'tk'
```

I've been googling for hours but can't deal with it. Kindly asking for your assistance.
I know there's no reason to use classes in this situation, but I'm trying to learn how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't properly initializing your class.

Remove this line which is creating a *second* button:

```
self = tkinter.Button(rootfr, text = 'Test')
```

... and add this line, which properly initializes the current button:

```
tkinter.Button.__init__(self, text="Test")
```

Or even better if you're on python3:

```
super().__init__(text="Test")
```

Comment: Are there any specific advantage for `super().__init__()` ? over `tkinter.Button.__init__()`?

Comment: @CoolCloud: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222877/what-does-super-do-in-python