# How Method Resolution Order (MRO) is working in this Python code

Tags: python, oop, multiple-inheritance, super

```
class parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a=2
        self.b=4
    def form1(self): 
        print("calling parent from1")
        print('p',self.a+self.b)
 
class child1(parent):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a=50
        self.b=4
    def form1(self):
        print('bye',self.a-self.b)
    def callchildform1(self):
        print("calling parent from child1")
        super().form1()
 
class child2(parent):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a=3
        self.b=4
    def form1(self):
        print('hi',self.a*self.b)
    def callchildform1(self):
        print("calling parent from child2")
        super().form1()
 
class grandchild(child1,child2):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a=10
        self.b=4
    def callingparent(self):
        super().form1()
 
g=grandchild()
g.callchildform1()
```

In the above code, when I call `g.callchildform1()`, according to MRO rule, the method will be first searched in the same class, then the first parent (child1 here) and then the second parent (child2).
As expected, it calls `child1.callchildform1()` and executes the first line `print("calling parent from child1")`. But after this, I expected that the next line `super().form1()` will be executed which will call `parent.form1()` but this doesnt happen. Instead, `child2.form1()` is being called. Please explain why this happens?

Comment: Check ```grandchild.__mro__```.

Comment: @HenryTjhia I have printed the MRO for this here: https://ideone.com/dhbhvT What I dont understand is, how and why is the code jumping from line 16 to line 24.

Comment: The result should be self-explainatory. Basically ```super``` routing through that ```tuple``` result.

Comment: @HenryTjhia On line 17, when `super().form1()` is called, it calls `child2.form1()` because in the MRO hierarchy, `child2` is the parent (super() in child1 will return child2) of `child1`. Is this correct?

Comment: Why would ```child2``` become parent of ```child1```? Both ```child1``` and ```child2``` are parent of ```grandchild```, which in turn have ```parent``` as their ```superclass```. ```parent``` itself has implied ```object``` as their ancestor. You are calling method through instance of ```grandchild``` as consequence should follow ```grandchild``` ```mro``` pattern.

Comment: @HenryTjhia In the link I posted in my earlier comment, what is returned by `super()` on line 17? Is this line executed? If yes, then why dont I see line 6 being printed since `parent` is the super class of `child1`?

Comment: Because after ```child1``` call, the next executed method is ```form1``` in the ```child2``` then stop because there is no any ```super``` remaining! If you want the parent's method also executed, you can do so by adding a ```super``` call in the ```form1``` of ```child2```.

Comment: @HenryTjhia 1) `child1` and `child2` are parents of `grandchild`. 2) `parent` is parent of both `child1` and `child2` and grandparent of `grandchild`. Now when I call `callchildform1` on `g` which is instance of grandchild, MRO first looks for this method in `grandchild`, since theres no method of this name, it looks in its parent which is `child1`. There the method is found and it starts executing it, starting line 15. On line 17, `child1` calls `super.form1()` but since parent of `child1` is `parent` class, shouldnt line 17 jump to  `form1` method in `parent` class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) has a great explanation of how `super()` works:

> **`super([type[, object-or-type]])`**
>
> Return a proxy object that delegates method calls to a **parent or sibling** class of type. This is useful for accessing inherited methods that have been overridden in a class.
>
> The `object-or-type` determines the *method resolution order* to be searched. The search starts from the class **right after** the type.

> For example, if `__mro__` of `object-or-type` is `D -> B -> C -> A -> object` and the value of type is `B`, then `super()` searches `C -> A -> object`.

`super()` is equivalent to the expression `super(__class__, self)` where `__class__` is an class object within whose method the `super()` is called. For example, `super()` within `grandchild.callingparent(self)` is essentially `super(grandchild, self)`. And `super()` inside `child1.callchildform1(self)` function is `super(child1, self)`.

`MRO` for `grandchild` is `(<grandchild>, <child1>, <child2>, <parent>, <object>)`. Therefore, according to the above excerpt from documentation, when `super().form1()` is called in `child1.callchildform1()`, which is equivalent to `super(child1, self)`, the search for the `form1` method **starts from the class right after the `child1`** in the `MRO` sequence and the first matching class with `form1` method is `child2`.

This occurs due to that you are using the diamond inheritance structure and the [principles](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) that underlie the MRO:

> with multiple inheritance hierarchies, the construction of the linearization is more cumbersome, since it is more difficult to construct a linearization that respects **local precedence ordering** and **monotonicity**.

When designing such hierarchies, it is need to follow the approach of **cooperative inheritance**, an explanation can be found, in this already classic [article](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/).