# Calling constructors of both parents in multiple inheritance in Python (general case)

Tags: python, inheritance, super, diamond-problem

I'm trying to figure out the multiple inheritance in Python, but all articles I find are limited to simple cases. Let's consider the following example:

```
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self, name: str) -> None:
        self.name = name
        print(f'Creating a Vehicle: {name}')

    def __del__(self):
        print(f'Deleting a Vehicle: {self.name}')


class Car(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self, name: str, n_wheels: int) -> None:
        super().__init__(name)
        self.wheels = n_wheels
        print(f'Creating a Car: {name}')

    def __del__(self):
        print(f'Deleting a Car: {self.name}')


class Boat(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self, name: str, n_props: int) -> None:
        super().__init__(name)
        self.propellers = n_props
        print(f'Creating a Boat: {name}')

    def __del__(self):
        print(f'Deleting a Boat: {self.name}')


class Amfibii(Car, Boat):
    def __init__(self, name: str, n_wheels: int, n_props: int) -> None:
        Car.__init__(self, name, n_wheels)
        Boat.__init__(self, name, n_props)
        print(f'Creating an Amfibii: {name}')

    def __del__(self):
        print(f'Deleting an Amfibii: {self.name}')


my_vehicle = Amfibii('Mazda', 4, 2)
```

I want to understand the order of calling constructors and destructors, as well as the correct and general use of the 'super' keyword.
In the example above, I get the following error:

> `super().__init__(name)`
> TypeError: `Boat.__init__()` missing 1 required positional argument: 'n_props'

How should I correctly call constructors of both parents, which have different sets of constructor arguments?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How Method Resolution Order (MRO) is working in this Python code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64740117/how-method-resolution-order-mro-is-working-in-this-python-code)

Comment: That is quite tricky… Python is building a dependency graph or so, but the catch is that you do not get to know it. 
To avoid getting this error, make the super constructor independent of specific arguments/named arguments with *args and **kwarks.

Comment: @Fylyp You do get to know it. All you need to do its call `mro()` on the class to see how the `super()` resolves parent classes.

Comment: @matszwecja It's useful, but doesn't seem to answer the question of how to call constructors of both parents, which have different sets of constructor arguments.

Comment: @Fylyp Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comments and the following article, I understood it. https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/

1. Regarding the constructors' arguments, they should be named. In this way, every level strips what it needs and passes it to the next one using `super()`
2. Every class calls `super().__init__()` only once. The following classes in the MRO order are responsible for continuing the initialization.

The updated example:

```
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self, name: str) -> None:
        self.name = name
        print(f'Creating a Vehicle: {name}')

    def go(self):
        print('Somehow moving...')
        assert not hasattr(super(), 'go')


class Car(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self, n_wheels: int,  **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.wheels = n_wheels
        print(f'Creating a Car: {self.name}')

    def go(self):
        print('Riding...')
        super().go()


class Boat(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self, n_props, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.propellers = n_props
        print(f'Creating a Boat: {self.name}')

    def go(self):
        print('Swimming...')
        super().go()


class Amfibii(Car, Boat):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        print(f'Creating an Amfibii: {self.name}')

    def go(self):
        print('Riding or swimming...')
        super().go()


my_vehicle = Amfibii(name='Mazda', n_wheels=4, n_props=2)
my_vehicle.go()
```

It's a bit cumbersome (gently speaking), isn't it?

EDIT: I updated the code according co the comments.

Comment: I would omit `*args` from each definition of `__init__` as well. One of the things recommended by the linked article is that you use *only* keyword arguments. Note that you can write, for example, `def __init__(self, *, n_props, **kwargs):` for `Boat.__init__`, and not only will no additional positional arguments be accepted, but `n_props` itself must be specified with a keyword argument.

Comment: Unrelated, you can almost certainly dispense with the `__del__` methods. `__del__` doesn't quite correspond to the destructors you might be familiar with in C++ or Java, and are only needed in certain rare circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        self.name = kwargs['name']
        print(f'Creating a Vehicle: {self.name}')


class Car(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.wheels = kwargs['n_wheels']
        print(f'Creating a Car: {self.name}')


class Boat(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.propellers = kwargs['n_props']
        print(f'Creating a Boat: {self.name}')

    def __del__(self):
        print(f'Deleting a Boat: {self.name}')


class Amfibii(Car, Boat):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print(f'Creating an Amfibii: {self.name}')

    def __del__(self):
        print(f'Deleting an Amfibii: {self.name}')
```

Note: But I would consider this as bad coding style!

Comment: Why would that ba a bad style and how to do it right, then?

Comment: I would consider upvoting if the answer was edited to address Karol's comment. Right now this answer reads a bit like "Here is some bad advice: ...", which is not really helpful.

Comment: You are right, I upvoted Karols Comment.