# Python classes inheritance issue

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I have the following classes for a game of black jack.

```
class Player:
    
    def __init__(self, player, balance=0): 
        self.player = player
        self.balance = balance
        
    def __str__(self):
        return f'Player:   {self.player}\n Balance:  ${self.balance}'
        
    def bet(self):
        print(self.balance)


class Dealer(Player):
    
    def __init__(self):    
        pass
```

I am trying to call the `bet` method from `Player` class through the `Dealer` class but am getting the following error when I `print(self.balance)`.

```
AttributeError: 'Dealer' object has no attribute 'balance'
```

I changed this to `print(Player.balance)` but this does not work either. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

```
name = input("Enter your full name:        ")   
balance =int(input("Enter the amount you would like to place on the table?  "))
    
my_player = Player(name, balance)    


my_dealer = Dealer() 
my_dealer.bet()
```

Comment: `__init__` of `Dealer` overridden the `__init__` of `Player` class

Comment: AttributeError: 'Dealer' object has no attribute 'balance'

Comment: Because `Dealer`'s `__init__()` doesn't initialise `self.balance`, that attribute doesn't exist. You need to either not provide a `__init__()` method on `Dealer` (so `Player`'s __init__ is used, i.e. you have to provide player and option balance), or `Dealer`'s __init__() needs to have parameters which call super().__init__() with those params.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does 'super' do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222877/what-does-super-do-in-python)

Comment: If your dealer doesn't have a balance, consider having it not be a subclass of player.

Comment: @unaied Try to always provide errors in the question itself by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65719539/edit) it.

Answer (score 3):

Python doesn't automatically call `__init__` for super classes. You need to call super in your Dealer class

```
class Dealer(Player):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(..., ...)
...
```

In your case, you're not using the Dealer's `__init__` so you can remove it completely, in which case it'll inherit its super implementation anyway.

Comment: I did this which seems to have fixed one part of the issue but when the value of balance is updated and I print the self.balance again it returns the original value and not the updated one

Comment: can I make the self.
balance a global attribute

Comment: balance is an attribute of `self`. How are you updating it?

Comment: self.balance -= bet_amt

Comment: Without seeing the full code I couldn't say why it was not appearing to be updated.

Comment: can I add the full code here or I could add to a github?

Comment: I have saved the rough working file here https://github.com/unaied/BlackJack/blob/main/working_file

Comment: You are recreating the `Dealer` instance on each loop. It is also using the global `player` and `balance` values used to create the player. You 're  probably better off removing the `Dealer`'s `__init__`.

Answer (score 1):

Nice works bro! You just miss a little thing when you inherit a class. At `__init__` method, you need to pass a statement: `super().__init__(...)`. In (...), you have to pass all the attributes of the parent class have. After that, you can call the attributes and methods of the parent class.