# Invoking other class/object methods from inside the class

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

Suppose I have the following code:

```
class Classy:
    def other(self):
        print("other")

    def method(self):
        print("method")
        self.other()


obj = Classy()
obj.method()
```

The output:

```
method
other
```

So I invoke another object/class method from inside the class. I invoke the other method within the 'method' method.

Now if I run the following code:

```
class Classy:
    def other(self):
        print("other")

    def method(self):
        print("method")
        Classy.other(self)


obj = Classy()
obj.method()
```

The output is the same. Now my question is: What is the difference between these two?

I am not sure if it is just a different style of calling - so it is basically the same - or if there is a difference in the logic. If yes, I would be interested in an example where the difference matters.

Comment: What is `self` is an instance of a class that _inherits_ from `Classy`, and _overrides_ `other`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the purpose of the word 'self'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-word-self)

Comment: The code: `Classy.other(self)` is what python turns: `self.other()` into. It is more conventional to use the latter.

Comment: @quamrana it is **not** just a matter of convention, in any non-trivial case the _behaviour_ can be different.

Answer (score 0):

Let's set it up so we can run them side by side:

```
class Classy:
    def other(self):
        print("Classy.other")
    def method(self):
        print("Classy.method")
        self.other()

class NotClassy:
    def other(self):
        print("NotClassy.other")
    def method(self):
        print("NotClassy.method")
        NotClassy.other(self)
```

So far, so good:

```
>>> Classy().method()
Classy.method
Classy.other
>>> NotClassy().method()
NotClassy.method
NotClassy.other
```

But what if *inheritance* gets involved, as it so often does in [oop](/questions/tagged/oop)? Let's define two subclasses that inherit `method` but override `other`:

```
class ClassyToo(Classy):
    def other(self):
        print("ClassyToo.other")

class NotClassyToo(NotClassy):
    def other(self):
        print("NotClassyToo.other")
```

Then things get a bit problematic; although the subclasses have almost identical implementation, and the parent classes seemed to behave exactly the same, the outputs here are different:

```
>>> ClassyToo().method()
Classy.method
ClassyToo.other
>>> NotClassyToo().method()
NotClassy.method
NotClassy.other  # what about NotClassyToo.other??
```

By calling `NotClassy.other` *directly*, rather than invoking the method on `self`, we've bypassed the overridden implementation in `NotClassyToo`. `self` might not always be an instance of the class the method is defined in, which is also why you see [`super`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/222877/3001761) getting used - your classes should *cooperate* in inheritance to ensure the right behaviour.