# New to code and bad at inheritance. Trying to make randomized tictactoe AI python3

Tags: python

I'm trying to make an AI that plays with the player but it keeps giving me a `TypeError`:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'sign'.
```

```
from random import choice
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name, sign, board = None):
        self.name = name  # player's name
        self.sign = sign  # player's sign O or X
        self.board = board
    def get_sign(self):
        # return an instance sign
        return self.sign
    def get_name(self):
        # return an instance name
        return self.name
    def choose(self, board):
        # prompt the user to choose a cell
        # if the user enters a valid string and the cell on the board is empty, update the board
        # otherwise print a message that the input is wrong and rewrite the prompt
        # use the methods board.isempty(cell), and board.set(cell, sign)
        while True:
            cell = input(f"{self.name}, {self.sign}: Enter a cell [A-C][1-3]:\n")
            cell = cell.upper()
            #checks to see if input matches to a cell and if the cell is empty
            if cell == "A1" or cell == "B1" or cell == "C1" or cell == "A2" or cell == "B2" or cell == "C2" or cell == "A3" or cell == "B3" or cell == "C3":
                if board.isempty(cell):
                    board.set(cell, self.sign)
                    break
                else:
                    print("You did not choose correctly.")
            else:
                print("You did not choose correctly.")

class AI(Player):
    def __init__(self, name, sign, board = None):
        super().__init__(board)
        self.sign = sign
        self.name = name
    def choose(self, board):
        valid_moves = ["A1", "A2", "A3", "B1", "B2", "B3", "C1", "C2", "C3"]
        cell = choice(valid_moves)
        board.set(cell, self.sign)
```

I call it in another file like this:

```
    player1 = AI("Bob", "X", board)
```

Comment: `super().__init__` is `Player.__init__`, who is defined as `def __init__(self, name, sign, board = None):`, but you call it with only one parameter: `super().__init__(board)`...

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Wow so simple, thank you. Mind if I clarify something, I thought super() meant you take what attributes you wanted from the previous class? What is the relation between the parameters in 
def __init__(self, name, sign, board = None): and 
super().__init__(name, sign, board)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does 'super' do in Python? - difference between super().\_\_init\_\_() and explicit superclass \_\_init\_\_()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222877/what-does-super-do-in-python-difference-between-super-init-and-expl)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the inherited class `AI`.

In this class, you have created `__init__` with 3 parameters and inside this `__init__` you are calling the `__init__` of the parent class, and this parent class is `Player`. But if you check the `Player` class, you will see that its `__init__` has 3 parameters of which two are mandatory: `name` and `sign`.

In the AI class, replace

```
super().__init__(board)
```

by

```
super().__init__(name,sign,board)
```

Comment: Please add some code snippet to give better understanding.
See how to give answer on StackOverflow and keep contributing. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Thank you. I would upvote if I could. Can you possibly explain why I'm defining the parameters in both 
`def __init__(self, name, sign, board = None):`
`super.__init(name,sign,board)` I thought if you inherit attributes it doesn't need to be specified?

Comment: @blake You do inherit attributes, but since you are calling the parent class' `__init__` (`Player.__init__`), you still need to pass in the correct set of arguments. It's not about attributes, but correct function calls.

Comment: @GinoMempin Thank you and also the link you sent helped a lot.