# Class inheritance via super with two arguments

Tags: python, class, inheritance

In the below code, i replaced args with numbers to demonstrate what classes are inherited.

```
class Animal:
  def __init__(self, animalName):
    print(animalName, 'is an animal.');

class Mammal(Animal):
  def __init__(self, mammalName):
    print(mammalName, 'is a mammal.')
    super().__init__(mammalName)

class CannotFly(Mammal):
  def __init__(self, mammalThatCantFly):
    print('2', "cannot fly.")
    super().__init__('2')

class CannotSwim(Mammal):
  def __init__(self, mammalThatCantSwim):
    print('1', "cannot swim.")
    super().__init__('1')

# Cat inherits CannotSwim and CannotFly
class Cat(CannotSwim, CannotFly):
  def __init__(self):
    print('I am a cat.');
    super().__init__('Cat')

cat = Cat()
```

returns

```
I am a cat.
1 cannot swim.
2 cannot fly.
2 is a mammal.
2 is an animal.
```

Why is it not the below?

```
I am a cat.
1 cannot swim.
1 is a mammal.
1 is an animal.
2 cannot fly.
2 is a mammal.
2 is an animal.
```

There are effectively two call streams, no?

Comment: Look at: `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_linearization`

Comment: No, there are not "two call streams". You call `Cat`, and each `__init__` makes exactly one call to `super`. Where do you think the extra calls would come from? `super()` just finds the *next* class in the MRO, not all parent classes of the current object.

Comment: Thanks @hussic and chepner, understood. Out of curiosity, is there a way to find all the parent classes? I mean, why super on CannotSwim(Mammal) does not go to Mammal class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the method resolution order (MRO) for `Cat`:

```
>>> Cat.mro()
[<class '__main__.Cat'>, <class '__main__.CannotSwim'>, <class '__main__.CannotFly'>, <class '__main__.Mammal'>, <class '__main__.Animal'>, <class 'object'>]
```

Each class appears *once* in the MRO, due to the [C3 linearization algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_linearization). Very briefly, this constructs the MRO from the inheritance graph using a few simple rules:

1. Each class in the graph appears once.
2. Each class precedes any of its parent classes.
3. When a class has two parents, the left-to-right order of the parents is preserved.

("Linearization", because it produces a linear ordering of the nodes in the inheritance graph.)

`super()` is misnamed; a better name would have been something lie `nextclass`, because it does *not* use the current class's list of parents, but the MRO of the `self` argument. When you call `Cat`, you are seeing the following calls.

1. `Cat.__init__`
2. `Cat.__init__` uses `super` to call `CannotSwim.__init__`
3. `CannotSwim.__init__` uses `super` to call `CannotFly.__init__`
4. `CannotFly.__init__` uses `super` to call `Mammal.__init__`
5. `Mammal.__init__` uses `super` to call `Animal.__init__`
6. `Animal.__init__` uses `super` to call `object.__init__`

`object.__init__` does not use `super` (it "owns" `__init__`), so the chain ends there.

In particular, note #3: `CannotSwim` causes its "sibling" in the inheritance graph to be used, not its own parent.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this post [What does 'super' do in Python? - difference between super().__init__() and explicit superclass __init__()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222877/what-does-super-do-in-python-difference-between-super-init-and-expl)

Now what it says is that `__init__` is called for every class in the instance's mro.
you can print that by doing `print(Cat.__mro__)` this will print out

`(<class '__main__.Cat'>, <class '__main__.CannotSwim'>, <class '__main__.CannotFly'>, <class '__main__.Mammal'>, <class '__main__.Animal'>, <class 'object'>)`

As you can see there is the order of the calls. Now, why '2' is used and not '1', see the answer in the comments by hussic