# Why does the super() call work in a Python class that derives from an ABC?

Tags: python, python-3.x, super, abc

I have a Python ABC (let's call it `A`) with a concrete `__init__()` method, as well as a class that implements this ABC (let's call it `B`). As far as I understand, I should **not** be able to instantiate the ABC.

**Question:** Why and how is the call `super().__init__()` inside the `__init__` function of class `B` working? I assume that `super()` creates an instance of the parent class - which in this case is the ABC.

##### Class A

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from util.fileManager import FileManager


class A(ABC):
    def __init__(self):
        self.file_manager = FileManager()  # Composition object

    ...
```

##### Class B, implementing class A

```py
from interfaces.A import A


class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    ...
```

#### Edit / Solution

> [What does 'super' do in Python? - difference between super().__init__() and explicit superclass __init__()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222877/)

As many of you've probably seen, this question really boils down to what `super()` does in Python. Accepting the answer I marked, I really want to point to the link in @KarlKnechtel's comment, since it helped me further understand the situation.

Comment: "I assume that super() creates an instance of the parent class - which in this case is the ABC." Are you aware that `super` can be used in other methods besides `__init__`? That rather makes it difficult for it to work that way, right? Instead, `super()` arranges for the parent's method to be called, *upon `self`*. It does not create an instance because one already exists. Please also see prior reference questions e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222877/.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel - the link you've provided actually helped be a lot to understand this concept and map it to my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`super()` does **not** create an instance of the parent.

An instance of `super` (it's a type, not a function) provides a *proxy* for for some set of classes so that an attribute lookup resolves to the correct class's value. Calling `super().__init__` simply starts looking in the MRO of `type(self)`, starting at `A`, for an attribute named `__init__`.

When arguments are explicitly provided to `super`, the second argument determines *whose* MRO you will search, and the first argument determines where in the MRO you start search (namely, the *next* class after the argument in the MRO).

An example with an extremely unorthodox use of `super`:

```
>>> class A:
...   def foo(self):
...     print("A")
...
>>> class B(A):
...   def foo(self):
...     print("B")
...
>>> b = B()
>>> x = super(B, b)
>>> type(x)
<class 'super'>
>>> x.__thisclass__
<class '__main__.B'>
>>> x.__self__ is b
True
>>> x.foo()
A
```

`super` itself doesn't really have optional arguments, but the context in which you almost always use it strongly *imply* which arguments should be passed, so Python 3 was engineered to supply them for you.