# difference between two types of super() function call

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance, super

I define a subclass ParserModel whic is  inherritted by `super(ParserModel, self).__init__()`. Can you tell me what if I use `super().__init__()`? What is the difference between this two?

```py
class ParserModel(nn.Module):
    """ Feedforward neural network with an embedding layer and two hidden layers.
    The ParserModel will predict which transition should be applied to a
    given partial parse configuration.

    PyTorch Notes:
        - Note that "ParserModel" is a subclass of the "nn.Module" class. In PyTorch all neural networks
            are a subclass of this "nn.Module".
        - The "__init__" method is where you define all the layers and parameters
            (embedding layers, linear layers, dropout layers, etc.).
        - "__init__" gets automatically called when you create a new instance of your class, e.g.
            when you write "m = ParserModel()".
        - Other methods of ParserModel can access variables that have "self." prefix. Thus,
            you should add the "self." prefix layers, values, etc. that you want to utilize
            in other ParserModel methods.
        - For further documentation on "nn.Module" please see https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html.
    """
    def __init__(self, embeddings, n_features=36,
        hidden_size=200, n_classes=3, dropout_prob=0.5):
        """ Initialize the parser model.

        @param embeddings (ndarray): word embeddings (num_words, embedding_size)
        @param n_features (int): number of input features
        @param hidden_size (int): number of hidden units
        @param n_classes (int): number of output classes
        @param dropout_prob (float): dropout probability
        """
        super(ParserModel, self).__init__()
        self.n_features = n_features
        self.n_classes = n_classes
        self.dropout_prob = dropout_prob
        self.embed_size = embeddings.shape[1]
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.embeddings = nn.Parameter(torch.tensor(embeddings))
```

I want to know the differecen between this two types of function call of the super() function.

Comment: TLDR: They do the same thing in Python 3 (in this context).

Comment: better dupe with more details: [What does 'super' do in Python? - difference between super().\_\_init\_\_() and explicit superclass \_\_init\_\_()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/222877)