# Class inheriting from itself in python

Tags: python, pytorch

I am fairly new to object oriented programming and I am learning neural networks with pytorch.

I have seen some examples where the class in python will inherit from itself (sub and super class will have the same name). Can someone please explain to me how does it work? I have put a small code as an example below.

```
import torch.nn as nn 


class LR(nn.module):
  def __init__(self, in_size, out_size):
    super(LR, self).__init__()
    self.linear = nn.Linear(in_size, out_size)

  def forward(self, x):
    out = self.linear(x)
    return out
```

I am auditing a pytorch course on coursera. The example is from the course. Here I am confused with the line `super(LR, self)`

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222877/what-does-super-do-in-python-difference-between-super-init-and-expl  In short however, its just an older syntax. The call is to the parent class constructor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does 'super' do in Python? - difference between super().\_\_init\_\_() and explicit superclass \_\_init\_\_()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222877/what-does-super-do-in-python-difference-between-super-init-and-expl)

Answer (score 1):

You might be mistaken in your assumption that you're seeing classes inherit from themselves. In the example you've posted `LR` inherits from `nn.module`, and `super(LR, self).__init__()` will be calling `nn.module`'s `__init__` method.

Comment: Then will it be the same as writing ``` super().__init__()``` ? Because that is how I am used to doing the inheritance.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Newer versions of Python support the syntax you mentioned here, whereas the syntax in your question is an older style syntax.