# How to resolve 'HybridVehicle.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument' in Python 3.x?

Tags: python, oop, multiple-inheritance

1. Created a Base class '**Vehicle**' having attributes **make**, **model**, and **year**

```
class Vehicle:

    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year

    def start(self):
        print("Starting the vehicle.")

    def stop(self):
        print("Stopping the vehicle.")

    def accelerate(self):
        print("Accelerating the vehicle.")

    def brake(self):
        print("Applying brakes.")
```

2. Now Created a Sub-class named **ElectricVehicle** having attribute **battery_capacity**

```
class ElectricVehicle(Vehicle):

    def __init__(self, make, model, year, battery_capacity):
        super().__init__(make, model, year)
        self.battery_capacity = battery_capacity

    def charge(self):
        print("Charging the battery.")

    def check_battery(self):
        print("Checking the battery level.")
```

3. Now Created a Sub-class named **HybridVehicle** having attribute **fuel_capacity**

```
class HybridVehicle(Vehicle):

    def __init__(self, make, model, year, fuel_capacity):
        super().__init__(make, model, year)
        self.fuel_capacity = fuel_capacity

    def refuel(self):
        print("Refueling the vehicle.")

    def check_fuel(self):
        print("Checking the fuel level.")
```

4. Finally Created class **HybridElectricVehicle** and inherited **ElectricVehicle** and **HybridVehicle**

```
class HybridElectricVehicle(ElectricVehicle, HybridVehicle):

    def __init__(self, make, model, year, battery_capacity, fuel_capacity, additional_property):
        super().__init__(make, model, year, battery_capacity)
        HybridVehicle.__init__(self, make, model, year, fuel_capacity)
        self.additional_property = additional_property
```

Creating an instance of HybridElectricVehicle

```
hybrid_electric_car = HybridElectricVehicle("Tesla", "Model 3", 2023, 75, 10, 'additional_property')
`
```

In this code i'm facing this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "multiple inheritance 2.py", line 52, in <module>

hybrid_electric_car = HybridElectricVehicle("Tesla", "Model 3", 2023, 75, 10, 'additional_property')
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "multiple inheritance 2.py", line 46, in __init__
    super().__init__(make, model, year, battery_capacity)
  File multiple inheritance 2.py", line 22, in __init__
    super().__init__(make, model, year)

TypeError: HybridVehicle.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'fuel_capacity'
```

Comment: Missing is  additional_property should be added.

Answer (score 0):

The traceback is showing you that `super().__init__` is calling `HybridVehicle.__init__`, which requires a `fuel_capacity`.

You've only passed make, model, year, and battery capacity

Both inherited class constructors will be called. [What does 'super' do in Python? - difference between super().__init__() and explicit superclass __init__()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222877/what-does-super-do-in-python-difference-between-super-init-and-expl)